# Why is there no dark theme on SO?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, dark-mode

I think SO should implement dark theme. All major interfaces have a dark theme because it's better for the eyes.

Comment: That is a shame for the whole web: the browser (for example chrome) adjusts his colors to the system theme, but there is no way to detect if the system theme is dark from a web application neither with css nor with javascript.

Comment: Good point! As using any kind of a User Style extension is gr8 as you could choose the theme that you prefer, I hope that SO would consider to make its one dark style that I can use without any extension as I'd prefer not to use one of such extensions for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: I've found another good reason to make an official Dark Theme. And is for accessibility purpose. For example I've got floater in my eyes and a dark background make my life easier! Hope SO team will take a Dark Them really into consideration.

Comment: I made a Stack Overflow Dark Theme userscript, which can be found on StackApps: https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-overflow-dark-theme

Comment: Yes! Windows, MSDN, Chrome, Skype, IDEs — all of them have **Dark Mode out-of-box**.

Comment: I understand you guys are busy and need to prioritize tasks.  That's fine.  But to *decline* the feature outright?  Especially since seemingly every other dev tool has or is actively working on a dark theme?  I do not understand.  Hacky user scripts that can break at any time are not a true alternative.

Comment: I though every developer wants dark mode on everythig? how come a site like stackoverflow does not support this

Comment: _because it's better for the eyes_ Is this just an opinion, or do you have a source somewhere to validate this claim?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I don't know if there is any actual proof whether a dark theme is better or not for healthy eyes, but I tell you the truth if I say that for eyes suffering floaters disease a dark them is a life saver. And so as floaters there should be some other eye disease that could take advantage from a dark theme. And just so I know... but don't you guys have your retina "burned out" (or flashed out) while coding at night? Think from an active answering user's point of view and not only from the point of view of a casual user asking few questions.

Comment: There's one now! https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/ This question should be reopened to include the link

Comment: Now a duplicate of [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits)

Comment: I now set everything in white mode, this is easier than dark mode. Then I type the shell command that magically passes all apps in dark mode a once: `xcalib -i -a`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552037/

Answer (score 493, accepted):

**Update March 2020:** After almost five years: it is here. [Stack Overflow introduces Dark Mode beta.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/) This appears to be for the main StackOverflow site only, but not any of the other sites. If you want a dark theme for other StackExchange sites, you may still want to try the browser extension below.

---

If you prefer browsing Stack Overflow with a dark theme (I do!), you can tell your browser to do so using *Stylus* - an extension available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/styl-us/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/Stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne), and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/stylus/). Stylus lets you apply any theme you want to any site.

For browsing Stack Overflow I really like [this dark theme](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark).

To use:

1. Install Stylus for your browser ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/styl-us/) / [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/Stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) / [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/stylus/))
2. [Click to install the CSS file from GitHub](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark/raw/master/stackoverflow-dark.user.css), which will open it in Stylus (or [visit the GitHub page](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark) and click on "Install the usercss" if you prefer)
3. In the new Stylus window, click "Install style" on the left:

[image: Screenshot of Stylus extension offering to install new style]

(if you don't see a big green button - make sure you have JavaScript enabled)

Preview of Dark Theme:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow, being viewed in a dark theme]

**SECURITY NOTE**: Previously there was an extension named "stylish" instead. Stylish has now turned into spyware and tracks your browser history. I do *NOT* recommend using it. Use Stylus. It is a clean, forked version with no tracking. See the [Stylus GitHub FAQ](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/wiki/FAQ) for details.

Comment: So how long are you with dark theme? How does it feel? I can't stand 5 minutes with a dark theme when it comes to reading. Sorry, I am just curious, I see sometimes people say to use it still, but I don't get it.

Comment: Problem with that is that I can't install any extension not allowed by my admin, and they don't seems to bother about that.

Comment: That one specifically actually seems to cause more eye strain that the normal style, which is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve with a dark theme in the first place. I would probably write my own if I were more committed to [so].

Comment: I like it. Just tried it. Out of interest are there other known dark themes to try too for SO using this plugin?

Comment: Also is there a theme like the dark one for MSDN library?

Comment: This is nice, although it should be built into the website.

Comment: Nice extension, but I don't understand, how can you turst it and allow to "Read and change all your data on the websites you visit"?

Comment: Unfortunately, Stylish is spyware, try googling "stylish spyware".

Comment: Consider using Stylus instead, as stylish was just pulled from all major addon distributors for spying on users.

Comment: The link for the Chrome extension is broken.

Comment: The reviews for Stylish are just pages and pages of people saying it steals your browsing history.

Comment: @styrofoamfly (and Insomniac and Kulahan) Thank you very much for the notice! I have edited the answer to point to Stylus instead.

Comment: Apparently this now gets blocked by FireFox ...

Comment: The link for the theme you mentioned should be: https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark (not StylusThemes)

Comment: It looks almost perfect in other language  sites (at least [StackOverflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com))

Comment: What about Safari?

Comment: For Chrome and Firefox this is OK, but it seems this Extension is not available for Edge.

Comment: this advice should be removed as it is promoting a malicious plugin that steals data, just google it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Please update the link to install the style, it's now present at `https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark/raw/master/stackoverflow-dark.user.css` and no longer downloadable from userstyles.org

Comment: @I.Am.A.Guy and jhscheer - Thank you for noting the updated links. I have fixed them. I added a screenshot, and copyedited as well. Hope this looks better now.

Comment: @styrofoamfly did you suggest to use one of the biggest industrial information collectors to search about a spyware? I find it a bit ironic. Yeah stylish steals your browsing history, google tracks it in real time yet people have no issue with that, what's the difference again?
(not arguing in favour of spyware, just wanted to point out how google isn't much different, it just does it after saying it will in an agreement no one reads)

Comment: @Andrew Truckle, yes, Microsoft Docs aka MSDN does provide **Dark Mode out-of-box**, as well as many other popular apps — Windows, Office, Chrome, Skype, IDEs, Media Players and many others.

Comment: Installing the extension evidently fixes Stack Overflow but breaks other Stack Exchange sites.  The only solution is to actually implement a native dark theme.

Comment: And any ideas about mobile version???

Comment: Why this is an accepted answer is a mystery IMHO. This is, at best, a workaround. And it's definitely not the answer to "why is there no dark theme?"...

Comment: Link for chrome is broken here!

Comment: Finally, after years of waiting, it arrived: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/

Comment: It's funny telling people to use an extension AND in the same answer saying an extension (albeit a different one) is a malware. That's the reason it should be built into the website and I'm glad it's finally here! Wish it'll be implemented across the whole stackexchange network of sites but that's of course an entirely different difficulty level, so maybe in 10 years. 

Comment: @k0pernikus Huzzah! I saw this also; thanks for reporting the beta :) I have added a link at the top. I will leave the rest of the answer intact, as a historical record, and because it may be needed for other StackExchange sites. Wow, a lot has happened in five years.

Comment: @Themelis [The Chrome link to the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/Stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) works just fine for me. What do you see when you open it?

Comment: You can do this with CSS, too. See [this CodeGolf Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18738/dark-mode-coming-here).

Comment: How do I disable it? I hate this theme. Wanna switch back to normal :(

Comment: Gotcha -> Edit Profile -> Site preference (or something like that. )

Answer (score 65):

Chrome 78 has automatic dark mode behind the #enable-force-dark flag.

1. Visit chrome://flags
2. search for #enable-force-dark.
3. Enable it

This enable inverted dark colors everywhere and certainly works well for Stack Overflow

Comment: Also work on Opera version 65

Comment: Also works on Brave 1.0.1.

Comment: And in Vivaldi as well (tested with 2.10.1745.27).

Comment: That's a very nice solution!

Comment: You don't need this anymore :) https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/

Comment: @blex That's only for SO. If you want meta, SO.blogs and other network sites to match, you need to use the flag until Dark Mode is network-wide.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, the question is exclusively about SO :)

Answer (score 34):

There are many browser extensions that will do the trick very nicely. Search for "dark reader" followed by your browser.

Here are a couple of examples.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh/related?hl=en  (Chrome)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/owl/ (Firefox - screenshot below)

[image]

A slight downside is you might need to turn off the extension for sites with naturally black backgrounds such as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Dark Reader works wonders!

Comment: For modern Firefox (Waterfox Classic included) you can use the extension "Dark Reader" by Alexander Shutau works perfectly https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/darkreader/   Whereas for legacy Firefox as Palemoon there is a extension "Advanced Night Mode" https://addons.palemoon.org/addon/advanced-night-mode/

Answer (score -7):

If you're in a Windows OS you can *always* activate high contrast and use Edge or Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: I believe this answer got so many down votes just because the sentence contains "Internet Explorer".

Comment: but he told IE11 not IE6! what is with you guys!?

Comment: @Reishin unfortunately people who didn't ever even try newer versions of IE keep blaming it for IE 6 faults.

Comment: @Reishin IE11 is also a dead browser that only receives critical security patches.

Comment: IE11 is also a very very bad browser for just about everything. Just look at compatibility tables.

Comment: @Sv443 just open it and navigate the internet, i've yet to find any website with issues unless the website itself has a dummy page that says "use another browser", and once you bypass it the website works perfectly fine.

Comment: I really wonder who up voted this :D

Comment: high contrast is not a night theme, please.

Comment: @victorf OP asked for a dark theme, not a night theme. High contrast can be made to a dark theme. A night theme is totally different and generally involves just reducing the amount of blue light.

Comment: As a frontend / backend developer I have spent tremendous amount of time making my UI works on IE 11. They already have retarded standards, but they aso have the crappiest developer tools. In other words, IE 11 is still IE

Comment: SO, IE, light theme should never coexist in the first place. There is a reason why our IDE / editor has a dark theme!

Answer (score -12):

A huge improvement could be achieved just by changing the `#FFFFFF` background color for something like `#F0F0F0`, which requires minimum effort but has great impact after a few hours of usage. Also, this would not bother any light-theme lovers!

I know this is not a dark-theme at all, but it's a nearly-effortless way of reducing eye-strain for the users without having to fully support a 2nd theme.

Comment: That's _nowhere near_ a dark theme, though.

Answer (score -85):

We have no plans to maintain two different styles for Stack Overflow at this time.

---

Update: no changes as of when I'm writing this in 2019. I personally would love to have a dark theme, but at the moment we don't have the resources to create and, more importantly, maintain one. (And that's even without thinking about all the other sites beyond Stack Overflow.)

See [this issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297) in our design library's repo for more context/discussion.

Comment: @Adam Lear Would adding support for `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` be an option?

Comment: @user3071284 That's basically the same thing as having a dark mode minus us tracking the user's preference on our end, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, it's not trivial, and to allow the user to choose, that would have to be tracked by SO. I was thinking only a subset of colors would have to be given the dark/light dichotomy and some colors would work with either as-is or could be identified to do so. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: If I might offer a suggestion... [Chrome has a new auto-darkness switch](https://9to5google.com/2019/07/16/chrome-canary-77-dark-mode/), so you'll soon get a dark mode, even if you didn't ask for it, even if you don't test it. My suggestion is that you either accept it as a fait accompli and add it to your testing regime, or else you try a somewhat rude override, e.g. `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` to disable it completely.