# Change the Stack Overflow white background color to a little darker

Tags: feature-request, design

The white background color here and on Stack Overflow is very bright. I would appreciate giving it a slightly darker color such as #FCFCFC.

**PROS:**

1. It's better for the eye health-wise
2. It makes the site easier to visit and might make lots of people more comfortable.

**CONS:**

1. Some people might not like it.

Preview:

[image]

Comment: I like it, actually.

Comment: That's probably your screen. I can hardly see a difference..

Comment: It already was requested and declined IIRC.

Comment: https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow EDIT: also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274388/why-is-there-no-dark-theme-on-so

Comment: @Floern adjust your contrast settings

Comment: *It's better for the eye health-wise* [citation-needed]

Comment: in chrome you can use care for your eyes plugin

Comment: I made a Stack Overflow Dark Theme userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-overflow-dark-theme

Comment: @SamuelLiew christ who are you and how did you find me 3 years later

Answer (score 11):

If you're not satisfied with the Stack Overflow theme (it is rather dull compared to some of the newly graduated sites), you can always create your own User Stylesheet / Injected Stylesheet (depending on which browser you use). Something like this – just changing a background color – is rather easy to apply and might be a good introduction in this topic. Know that there will *always* be people who do not like one particular feature of a certain design; it's hard to keep all ±5 million daily visitors of the site 100% satisfied.