# Can Stack Overflow support Dark Mode?

Tags: feature-request

Chrome 73 supports it. It looks like some CSS media selectors provide a standard way to support it.

Comment: There is a userscript for Stack Overflow dark mode. [link](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/StackOverflowDarkMode.user.js) \([direct install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/StackOverflowDarkMode.user.js)\)

Comment: Understand - this is a request to support the standard, now that there is one.

Comment: I don't see the company changing their stance just because `prefers-color-scheme` exists now.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, I recommend [following this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390841) in the duplicate post to  `#enable-force-dark`.