# Should Stack Overflow revisit the dark mode question in light of new situations in 2019 vs 2013 when it was first asked?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, dark-mode

Original issue from 2013: [Why is there no dark theme on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274388/why-is-there-no-dark-theme-on-so)?

It's 2019. Operating Systems have started having a user preference setting for a light UI or a dark UI. Windows 10, iOS 13 and MacOS 10.14 all support this.

The browsers now pass the user's preference through to the webpage via CSS via the media query for `prefers-color-scheme`. Safari and Firefox both have this shipping in the stable versions of their browsers. Chrome's is in Beta and will be stable soon (v76).

UPDATE: Chrome is now shipping this with the stable versions and a majority of users in the world (currently over 75%, per: https://caniuse.com/#feat=prefers-color-scheme) have the ability to have the browser identify if the user prefers light or dark color scheme. This is an accessibility issue for many users as well as a power saving option for mobile devices.

Should Stack Overflow respect the user's OS level preferences and support a dark mode directly? In other words without the user having to jump through hurdles, install userstyle css files or extensions but instead just respect the OS settings the user has selected?

It seems like the world has changed since 2013 when there was no OS level -> browser level user preference. While CSS is required to implement this no S.O. UX or user profile schema change is required. OS vendors and browser vendors are encouraging apps and webpages to support dark mode. Shouldn't S.O. reconsider in light of changing situations?

Comment: I feel like the priorities of SO Inc. are pretty outlandish. They abandoned the mobile app and don't include a mode which would be achievable with a pretty simple CSS swap.

Comment: I wonder who came up with the idea of a light theme in the first place!

Comment: I wonder why nobody mentions this is an accessibility issue.

Comment: @TamásSengel but there is a stackexchange app now. Which I like better

Comment: I think there are far more important things SO could spend time on. Fine tuning and evaluating the Ask a question wizard, for example. And if it proves to have the desired effect, consider porting that one SE-wide. As long as such things are the priority, then I couldn't care less if the default theme is light, dark or purple with unicorn gif animations.

Comment: @David the need for a dark theme is further proof that we're all heathens who have completely broken the idea and purpose of the web.

Comment: I don't know anybody who codes in an editor with a white background, for obvious reasons—I don't think I've ever even seen it. And as often as programmers reference SO as they code, one would think that a dark UI would have been an option from day 1. There's nothing like turning to a bright white screen to look something up on SO after hours of relaxed coding on a calming, dark UI.

Comment: Seriously!  Black text on white backgrounds is so completely stupid - the only reason we do it is because of some backwards lizard-brain hangup, a Pavlovian attraction to the familiar, that has carried over from print on white paper - a decidedly obsolete technology whose norms have no basis in reason when applied to an active luminescent display.  Just because it is possible to turn most of the pixels on the screen to 11 doesn't mean we should do it.

Comment: @J... - [White text on black is actually harder on your eyes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184828/178816). I wrote about it, in a very similar answer at MSE requesting this exact same feature. I do appreciate the humor though.

Comment: @TravisJ My eyes disagree. Also, the science and reasoning expressed in that post to justify said claims are highly questionable.  Black on white is perfectly sensible on paper or other reflective media.  Not on a luminescent display.

Comment: @J... - Well, if your eyes are in perfect health and not in need of correction, then by all means do what keeps them in that state.

Comment: @TravisJ  Previously I was merely talking about subjective comfort.  You're implicitly implying that white text on black will promote degradation of visual acuity, however.  Do you have any evidence to back up that implied statement?  I don't think it exists, to be honest.

Comment: @J... - It is not an implication though. I am stating that white text on black background will increase user levels of eye strain for the reasons outlined. You are free to debunk that, if you wish, or to believe otherwise. In addition, I also understand that some people do legitimately have issues with white backgrounds because of migraines (for example) so this isn't true for 100% of the population. However, it is true for a majority of users. As for evidence to that, I don't feel you even addressed the previous claims.

Comment: I have also taken a lot of time to speak with medical professionals on this matter, as my eyesight is perfect (at present fingers crossed), I use a computer sometimes 18 hours a day, and I would very much like to keep both my eyesight and productivity intact.

Comment: @TravisJ `I don't feel you even addressed the previous claims.` They're not worth addressing.  It's just a random opinion quoted from some random website that botches science so badly that it doesn't even merit consideration.

Comment: @Travis J That post literally says that white light is bad on your eyes. I don't see how you're saying that less white light coming from your screen is harder than more white light. Additionally it ignores the option of using a different color for the text, like literally any other color.

Comment: There is real science here. Just take it from Robert H. Shmerling, MD at Harvard: "The text and images on a computer screen are made up of pixels with blurry edges. The eyes have to work harder to focus on them compared with text and images on a printed page. This may lead to eye strain." Keep in mind, white text on a black background creates this effect more than black text on white background. [Harvard health](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/times-changin-bringing-new-syndromes-201607019844) goes on to state: "Optimize contrast. Black text on a bright white screen is best."

Comment: There is an abundance of study into this. Just take the time to read it. The only scenario where you may want a dark theme is if you have certain health conditions, if you prefer it aesthetically and are not concerned about eye strain, or if you are in a room with practically no light. These are not the majority of users though.

Comment: @TravisJ A random opinion from an MD's blog is not peer-reviewed science.  To the best of my knowledge there exists no legitimate science to suggest that light-on-dark or dark-on-light colour schemes contribute anything to deleterious eye damage over the other.  It's a subjective preference about subjective comfort.

Comment: @J... - It isn't random, there are studies by universities as well. There is a difference between "some random opinion" and a well informed expert relaying their research information. As you haven't really provided any sort of reference to your knowledge, in summation to this point it is null.

Comment: @TravisJ You're the one who has made a striking claim - that simply changing the colours on a monitor can promote eye injury.  I don't have to prove anything - you do.  By 'random' I mean it is a lone voice outside the sphere of peer-reviewed science.  I have not seen any real science to support what you suggest.

Comment: In fairness to everyone else reading this post who will at least review or research, here are just a few of the thousands of studies done highlighting the advantages of black text on white background (generally referred to as positive polarity): https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c349/6d9f1c9006bb2fd116e9a6b7b41c8659b237.pdf?_ga=2.235768513.1344830297.1561412918-854226796.1561412918 http://jdobr.es/pdf/Dobres-etal-2017-Ambient.pdf https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1605/c4f7d561f6cca0fcce6062f788562ccbae6f.pdf

Comment: @TravisJ That doesn't address the claim that black-on-white increases damage to the eye.  I'll grant that in certain lighting scenarios there are arguments in favour of balancing the average display luminosity with that of the ambient room, but that's not really about dark on light or light on dark.  You claimed dark-on-light would increase the risk of eye injury or damage.  You have shown no evidence for this.  I'm not being disrespectful, this is how science works.  I would be interested to read any such study - I'm not aware that any exists.

Comment: There seems to be an effort to change the definition of the original claim. It is abundantly clear to a rational person that there is more stress from negative polarity. There is an abundance of evidence that white text on a black background has negative impacts on the performance of the eye, as well as harming the ability to distinguish characters, and making it harder for the user to retain information. Any undue increase in effort by the eye is going to contribute to eye strain. That using a computer causes eyestrain is already well known and named, it is called Computer Vision Syndrome.

Comment: As someone with floaters, ocular migraines and general eye strain issues, I can say this is very much an accessibility issue. If you don't have these kinds of issues, it's hard for you to be able to know what those of us with these kinds of issues deal with. So dark mode is very much needed. I work around it with browser extensions or chrome flags, but that should not be necessary for this big of a site...

Comment: Just use #212121 as the background and #c0c0c0 as the text color. It's the perfect contrarst that won't burn your eyes and won't appear *horribly* on cheap monitors. How I long for SO to implement this.

Comment: I love the first comment that refers to "a pretty simple CSS swap". Compared to the effort shown in the blog post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/?cb=1

Answer (score 100):

## The current situation at Stack Exchange

To summarize staff member [Aaron Shekey](https://github.com/aaronshekey)'s comment on [this issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297) in Stack Exchange's GitHub repository, the new Stacks design doesn't have *code coverage*(?) to swap themes based on user-preference or OS setting.

A dark theme will also introduce additional complexity to support when developing new features or fixing existing bugs. This is not feasible when there are over 200 themes supporting about the same number of Network sites, as you would also have to test each one individually on top of testing desktop/tablet/mobile breakpoints.

While a dark theme is a highly-requested feature and one I would also welcome, I personally do not see this happening anytime soon even when it has been added to the [Roadmap](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/projects/1#card-20968934) as I understand the complexity involved.

## The next best solution

In the meantime, I have created a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) "**[Stack Exchange Dark Mode](https://stackapps.com/q/8053/9011)**" that works for **ALL Network sites** (*a bold claim, but try it out yourself!*), and supports all moderator/hidden pages as well (like post timelines). I am using this and will actively fix bugs when I come across them, especially when design changes.

My userscript also automatically does two levels of dark, which you can't implement using userstyles. There's a black/midnight mode for very late nights (10 pm-6 am), and a dark-grayish mode all other times.

### Features

- Supports all network sites, not just Stack Overflow!
- Works on Chat.SO, Chat.SE, Chat.MSE!
- Dual dark themes - midnight black for late nights
- Inverts SVG colours
- Some elements have reduced opacity until focused/mouseover (sidebar modules/images/timestamps). Some important colours are retained.
- Code highlighting in darker colours
- Darker post revision colours
- Dark code snippet editor
- Ensures no blinding white elements even if SO adds new features in future
- Works on all ~66 SOMU userscripts ([found here](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts))
- Support for SO, SU, SF, and other network site logos (instead of just plain white)
  [image]
- [Open source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

**[Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/StackExchangeDarkMode.user.js)**

Comment: I'm using Sam's dark theme and can report that barring some minor hiccups like inconsistencies with background blended images on certain site themes (who honestly cares, anyways), the dark mode userscript works wonders and hasn't broken anything substantial for me yet, having tested it on more then 30 network sites so far.

Comment: It works all too well. This is pure witchcraft.

Comment: Oh and it also works well on chat.SE, chat.SO, chat.MSE and SEDE

Comment: Writes a **bold claim** in bold. when meta is so meta.. https://xkcd.com/917/

Comment: This is what I love about this community. Everybody is so talented in different ways and uses that talent to help us all. Good question aksed, perfect answer given 1 hour later. And great tool Sam!

Comment: Is the caveat that the userscript doesn't have code coverage either? Otherwise I'm struggling to see how it's easy in one and not the other...? (n.b. I cannot install userscripts on my company machine)

Comment: @Pureferret the caveat is it's not guaranteed to work for every aspect of every site, and is unofficial

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your post basically says "*it's not feasible, but here, I made it*". If you've created a script that supports "**all network sites**", then why can't SE just use that script, or do something themselves?

Comment: Also, I feel like supporting StackOverflow would already be a huge plus, because it's the largest site and developers work late night  Plus, the question reads "*should **StackOverflow** revisit dark mode*", not StackExchange.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth the two sites are tied together for ease of development reasons I would imagine. Not-feasible to test is probably the blocker not unfeasible to do.

Comment: Dark Reader works fine with StackExchange. Bonus: You get dark mode for the rest of the web as well :)

Comment: So "dark mode" is a no go because of _complexity_, yet **each** exchange site [can have its own theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes)? If individual users can do it, like [here](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark), [here](https://userstyles.org/styles/164922/stackoverflow-neon), [here](https://userstyles.org/styles/170507/new-dev-s-dark-stackoverflow) and [here](https://userstyles.org/styles/131249/dev-s-dark-stackoverflow) to name a few, then surely a team of developers can figure something out.

Comment: It's amazing what a single developer with a good attitude can do. But when a bunch of people gets into a scoping meeting the difficulty gets multiplied. Great job @samuel-liew

Comment: `the new Stacks design doesn't have code coverage to swap themes based on ... OS setting` — That's not someting Stack has to figure out; a native media query is supported (or will be in the near future) in multiple browsers.

Comment: Maintaining two themes is not feasible? Ok, just abandon the light one then...

Comment: Four to six week then, I guess. Since you mentioned a roadmap.

Comment: I had to google it. It's `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { ... }` (also `light` and `no-preference`), supported in Chrome, Firefox and Safari (but not Safari on iOS). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: thanks Samuel, you've darkened my day.

Comment: Literally, all you gotta do is change colors of things...

Comment: if Aaron Shekey spent a fracton on the time he's spent telling us how difficult it is to implement and listing all the reasons why its impossible to do... he could have given us dark, high-contrast and glitter-pink unicorn themes. A 'can-do' attitude seems to be sorely lacking at SO these days.

Comment: So, let me get this straight. There's a JS that can be applied to the site to offer a dark-theme RIGHT HERE in this answer, but actually implementing this as an option that could be built-into the actual site is too complex? Oh, wait, @LinusGeffarth already wrote exactly this...

Comment: I use Stylus at home but if you're stuck in a locked-down corporate environment, plugin-based band-aids aren't very useful. Ridiculous that a site that is literally all about development claims a simple dev chore is just too hard.

Comment: It's blinding. I get up at 2:00 AM. Three screens in dark mode. Mellow. I come to stackoverflow and it's the elephant in the room. Glaring bright white on the browser. Ruins the whole setup. Please don't become like Craigslist.org stuck with a clunky old interface because it's too much trouble to change or people are stubborn. Dark Mode isn't a passing fad, it's here to stay.  People are going to increasingly seek options to hae it available.

Comment: _A dark theme will also introduce additional complexity to support when developing new features or fixing existing bugs_
This is always the case in software.

Comment: While everyone seems to be in love with dark themes I am one who does not get them at all and really dislike them. I find the contrast very hard on the eyes and even harder to read for any length of time. I may be an outlier but that's my 3 cents worth.

Answer (score 19):

Stack Overflow now has a dark mode, currently in beta. Thanks SO team!

https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/

[image]

Comment: Love it! When will it be implemented on the rest of the Stack Exchange sites (including Meta SO)?

Answer (score 2):

The Dark Reader browser extension/add-on works really well. It's automatic and doesn't require the web site designers to change their code on the web server.

Google Chrome:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh

Firefox:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/darkreader/

Safari:

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dark-reader-for-safari/id1438243180