# Why do blockquotes look different now?

Tags: discussion, design

> Why do blockquotes look different now?

I just refreshed the page and they look much more simple, but much less obviously a blockquote. Picture for reference:

[image]

Is this intentional? If so, what is the thought process behind changing something that is very recognisable to something that isn't?

*Update:*

Here is the css for a style to revert these changes (with thanks to @Glorfindel):

> blockquote { background: #fef8db; border-radius: 3px; }
>   blockquote::before { background: #fdeb8b; }
>   blockquote[class=""],blockquote.spoiler { background:
>   repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,#fff,#fff 15px,#eee 15px,#eee 20px);
>   }

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes

Comment: You'll get used to it.

Comment: @rene I'll use a userstyle

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz in that case, you might want to start from my attempt [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337985/295232).

Comment: With the old style most users put error messages in a blockquote, which had the effect of highlighting them in the question, making it *much* easier to scan read. This new change is a big step backwards in that regard.

Comment: How do you use the style? How can you make it apply to all readers of your posts?

Comment: I am unable to affect how other people see blockquotes, but I can use a browser extension to change how I see them. Something like [Styling](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/styling-public/) for Firefox.

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz You're not _supposed_ to affect how other people see it. Markup (or, in this case, Markdown) describes the meaning of parts of your post, not the way it looks. You're specifically not supposed to use markup to control the way it looks. That's the web designer's job. Just keep writing awesome (plain text!) content and let Stack Overflow present it according to the semantics you've described using your markup.

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz I'm not "telling you off"..... if you post a comment on a public thread expect to get responses... sorry.....

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz I'm not trying to "teach" you, I was trying to add my 2p to the ongoing discussion of which you and I are merely two cogs. Kinda wishing I hadn't; let's just leave it.

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz Could you suggest something new for items which need to stand out, such as verbatim error messages? Maybe a pre block with a coloured background?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional because to quote Aaron:

> I’ve landed where I’ve started

Over on Meta Stack Exchange this was discussed as [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes)

The issues they tried to address  were

- the yellow backgrounds were overpowering, reducing the contrast of the quote itself.
- increase visible differences between block quotes and spoilers and between code and quotes.
- works for backgrounds that aren’t perfectly white.
- improve blockquote nesting

There were several answers and comments that offered alternatives or tried to convince that this changes would have unwanted side-effects.

As it now became clear, this probably didn't fit in the grand-scheme of the move to the [Stacks design system](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/) with its defined color scheme. I assume this change makes things cleaner for other sites and easier to make changes down the line for all sites, most likely related to responsiveness and theming, if not [dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386150/should-stack-overflow-revisit-the-dark-mode-question-in-light-of-new-situations).

Comment: Could it be that the "grand scheme of things" is something that is upsetting a lot of the regulars in Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @AndrewMorton could be. I didn't do a Loop to gather thoughts. Do you think that is warranted?

Answer (score -4):

Personally, I think this change is excellent.

People have been *way* abusing the "it stands out" by using quote formatting for announcements, headings, notices & emphasis. **That's not what quote formatting is for.**

So, if you've been relying on it, consider this a lesson well learned: don't rely on specific formatting for your markup, but instead use the appropriate markup for the semantics of your text.

It's also prettier and more conventional this way; email clients have been using this formatting for quoted text for decades. I wish Outlook still did!

Comment: I don't agree that removing the highlighting of quotes is the way to go, because quotes should be highlighted. I do agree that it was abused, though. Especially for errors and entire stacktraces :(

Comment: @Scratte _"because quotes should be highlighted"_ Why?

Comment: To give them a clear visible contrast, so they in no way can be confused with the rest of the text. In my opinion quotes are special simply because they are quotes. I'd be fine with a box of gray edges all around. That would't be "highlighting", but it would be clear separation. I'm not even sure I'm making sense.

Comment: @Scratte No, you're making sense. I don't necessarily agree, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: The many posts on the subject did make me think that **maybe** there should be a highlighting option to completely avoid quote-markdown being misused. But that's a separate matter altogether.

Comment: @Scratte Agree that's potentially worth considering (separately)

Comment: Your primary argument is that *some* people have been abusing the formatting, so everyone shouldn't have formatting which is possible to abuse (effectively, "you can't have nice things, because someone has abused it"). If people are abusing the formatting, then edit the post to remove it. I don't recall seeing anyone argue that the formatting should be more distinctive because they want to abuse it. It *feels like* you're assuming bad faith on the part of people who prefer to have the quote formatting be more distinctive. That may not be your intent, but your emphasis gives that impression.

Comment: @Makyen That's not my argument at all, and I'm not assuming that at all, regardless of what you think my intent is. Seems lately you're just finding a way to sh!t-talk every single comment or post I write and it's a bit tiresome mate. Your last comment was incredibly condescending. Please stop.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings 60% to 75% of your answer here is about people abusing blockquote formatting. It's what you've put in bold both here and in [your comment on the other question](/q/394644/#comment760008_394644). Given what you've said, how you've emphasized it, and that you've repeated it, I think it's fairly reasonable for me to come away with the impression that abuse of blockquote formatting is your primary argument/issue. I've been trying to keep an open mind that it might not be your intent, but what you've written does make it look like that's your main concern.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings As far as I know, prior to my comment immediately preceding this one, I'd made a total of two comments about comments or on posts which you've made. One was my first comment here and the other is in the comments I linked above. I saw the one linked above because I was already interacting with that question. This one drew my attention because it popped up on the active questions list when you answered. I'm not following you around and have no idea what other posts or comments you've made. It's not my intent to be condescending or attack you. I'm sorry it feels that way.