# Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits

Tags: discussion, design, announcement, dark-mode

**With the full launch of Dark Mode on 17 June 2020, we've  shut down this post as a way to get feedback and bug reports.** Thank you to the many people who have posted answers, comments, and done the curation work of keeping this post in order so that Aaron could more easily find and address the issues. As of posting, Aaron has updated the status of all the posts in the [compilation answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/4548692).

There are some outstanding issues, particularly related to the Developer Story page, which is difficult to fix without breaking a lot of things. There are also a handful of items that we've deferred acting on but there shouldn't be anything critical that is left. Being out of beta doesn't mean we won't look at these or new bugs brought to our attention, only that we feel this project is stable and ready to go.

Our team working on this is pretty small but they're excited to have this project in a good place so they can move on to other things like working on getting the rest of the site responsive.

### From today on, If you find new bugs, please post them as a new question here on MSO.

---

Thank you so much for your interest in helping us find bugs in our dark mode version! The response to this has been amazing! My one request is that you look through existing answers before posting a new one. Nearly all of the newer answers I’ve gotten have been identified previously so the answers are duplicates!

For those of y’all waiting for fixes, we’re already working on many of them and you should start seeing status tags added to the answers soon. We appreciate your help and feedback!

—-

For years the answer to "can we have dark mode" has been a resounding "no!" Because of a huge number of [technical complexities](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297), which our design systems lead [Aaron discusses in this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/), creating dark mode has been too big of a project to take on with such a small team. You can read a bit about it in [this discussion about dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386150/should-stack-overflow-revisit-the-dark-mode-question-in-light-of-new-situations).

As Aaron’s been working on building [Stacks styles](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/356) and he and the other developers have been gradually converting site elements to Stacks, Dark Mode was finally in reach for development. We've had Dark Mode in mind with our Stacks updates since July 2019 and started really focusing on it for the last two months.

### Starting today Dark Mode is in beta for all *logged-in* users on Stack Overflow

It’s going to be a long road to complete this project but we felt that we were finally in a place where we could get your help finding all of the long tail bits we may have missed. For now, this is Stack Overflow in English *only* at this point - it doesn’t even work on MSO currently. The beta test will also be active on any Teams you may be on, so switching between the two shouldn’t cause blindness.

Thank you so much for your patience with us in getting this out. It’s been really neat to see the work some of y’all have done in creating userscripts to emulate dark mode here on SO and I hope you enjoy our version of it. I’ve been pestering Aaron with bugs for the last couple of weeks and I’m sure he’s going to love getting them from all of you!

### Beta means some pages are out of scope

There are some parts of Stack Overflow that are currently opted out during the beta for various reasons. These include:

- Homepage of Stack Overflow for non-logged in users
- Jobs
- Talent client portal

### How to enable it:

To enable this, visit your Stack Overflow profile, go to the "Edit profile and settings" tab, scroll down to "Preferences" under "Site Settings" and find the "Theme" section at the top of the page. You have three options - light, dark and "system setting" which will adjust the theme based on what your system prefers.

[image: Screenshot of the preferences page, showing the three options, light, dark, and system setting.]
(click the image to see a gif of the path)

### How to give feedback:

Write an answer below. Be sure to give us the following information:

- Description of the issue
- Screenshot of the issue
- Link to the page you’re seeing this problem

There are a couple of issues we’re already aware of that we’re working on but weren't able to clean up before release:

#### Badges

- We still need to do an audit of our badges and see if we can simplify them a bit on our way to dark mode.

#### Various tabs

- There are still some legacy filter tabs on a few pages that we need to convert to newer components.

#### Tables

- Mostly impacts moderator (`/admin`) pages, though there are a couple on `/tools` pages.

### Future releases

At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our LESS easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

If you have questions about dark mode on the network, please ask them on MSE rather than here.

---

In addition to bug reports, let me know if you have any questions or things I can clarify.

Comment: Thank you! Exciting to see such developments.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to my monitor not being that great - that's why I'm not posting as an answer here - but I'm having a hard time differentiating between bronze and silver badges when looking at them against the dark background. It's not impossible - I do notice a small difference - it's just somewhat hard to tell. BTW, In some places (for example, on Activity>Badges) it's not possible to know which are which just from context, and the color is the only way to differentiate them.

Comment: Nice, was expecting an April joke, but was offered something much better :)

Comment: Could this possibly be extended into chat.SO?

Comment: Not really a fan of dark mode, but it is extremely encouraging to see a feature that so many users in the community clamored for for so long. Well done!

Comment: This is great; thank you very much Catija, Aaron, and the rest of the team! Can't wait to see it make its way to Meta.

Comment: ... OK... so... I'm not sure what y'all think about things... we're getting a handful of different kinds of answers below - some things are bugs with one bug per answer and others are huge digests of many bugs... some answers are FRs and some are a combo of bugs and FRs... some of the digests include individual answers. I usually prefer single answers but I'm wondering if it makes sense to have one big bug wiki answer and FRs as separate answers... or something else... thoughts?

Comment: @Catija It might be easier to ask that *feature requests* be posted to a new thread. Unfortunately I don't think mods can migrate answers in a pick-and-choose fashion. But I think the vast majority of responses here are bugs, not FRs, so maybe the initial Q could include the existing FRs and whether they'll be addressed, and then a request for additional feature requests. That'd make the most sense to me for being able to separate bug fixing from new features internally.

Comment: YES!! Dark mode is 99% there. Biggest issue I see is syntax highlighting.If the color used is *Saturated*, then it will lack almost all contrast in dark mode. The same "color" can be used, but it needs to be de-saturated (using HSV values). The less saturation used, the more contrast with dark backgrounds there is (it doesn't effect light-mode to desaturate up to 50%+, but will make dark-mode readable) We know how much you try to stick to the international standard colors -- worth a check of the HSV values to see if they need tweaking for dark-mode.

Comment: It's almost perfect, but I'd like to see more lens-flares in the banner animation.

Comment: I was afraid this was an early April Fools joke due to the timing and the animated banner, and I'm so pleasantly surprised that it's real, and has been so lovingly crafted. This is a much tougher feature to implement in an established site. Thank you so much for taking the time to work on it! It looks *great.*

Comment: Wow, impressive to see how many people are putting effort into reporting all the little dark mode fails.

Comment: `background-color: #2d2d2d` is a bit too bright for me. The low contrast *looks* nice at first glance, but for longer periods of browsing, I prefer things a bit more contrasty: `background-color: #222` and `color: #ddd`. Luckily, there's always custom CSS styling...

Comment: As long as it's not enabled on meta, jobs, etc., I'll still use Dark Reader for this domain, so I won't really see the difference. But I'm looking forward to having an actually good-looking dark theme in which I can see whether I have clicked an upvote button (which doesn't work with Dark Reader, except in the ugly "Filter+" mode)!

Comment: I just came to meta (non-darkmode) from Darkmode main site, and I'm miserable now.

Comment: I hope the feature of dark mode will be added in meta too. Well done, stack team!

Comment: The "ultra" dark is really cool for really late night work, but still a little "too" dark, especially if you lower your screen brightness to adapt to other windows.

Comment: Just my two cents, but I _hate_ that desaturated orange used in the Overflow Blog panel.

Comment: Will darkmode be ported to other stack sites ? Or are they "independent" ?

Comment: According to [_The Overflow_](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow), Dark Mode is not going to be ported to other sites.

Comment: @EricSilveira Having "no plans" doesn't mean it's not going to happen. It just means that it's not on the calendar yet. As the rest of the paragraph says, it's a very complex project and is going to require a lot of work so we have to think carefully about it.

Comment: We're trying to help but if you scroll down and see the issues people are highlighting are being down voted. This is just discouraging tbh. I highlighted a issue that if you go to Watched tags and try to choose a tag, the drop down has issues with color contrast you can see yourself. and i get a down vote. others are experiencing the same. what is the point of asking for help if new contributors like me are just gonna get discouraged like that?

Comment: @HadiPawar I am guessing that the bug you’ve reported was already reported in one of the answers so it’s been downvoted because it’s a duplicate answer. I know it’s hard because there’s a ton of answers but it’s difficult for us to gauge what needs to be fixed if I have multiple answers saying the same thing. We love y’all for helping, we just need y’all to be thoughtful about checking existing answers before adding a new one.

Comment: I now set everything in white mode, this is easier than dark mode and, example given, this question shows how hard dark mode is. Then I type the linux shell command that magically passes all apps in dark mode a once: `xcalib -i -a` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552037/ )

Comment: @canon or how much they’re annoyed by the bugs.  I understand it’s hard. The format is what it is and having an alternative is good but not available. My comment is intended only to explain. I’m not able to prevent these votes, so the best solution I can offer is what I have. If you look at my first comment here, you can see I’ve been thinking about how to solve it. I’m still not sure. We could curate a list of reported bugs in the question or an accepted answer but I don’t have the time to do it and I’m not convinced people will read it any more than the 131 answers here.

Comment: I would like to point out that clicking on this post from Dark Mode Stack Overflow, coming to Light Mode Meta Stack Overflow *really makes my eyes bleed*.

Comment: The following pages are not dark, is it a desired behavior? https://stackoverflow.com/jobs, https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/developer-jobs, https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary
@Zoe

Comment: @Catija: Can we get some kind of update on when the *known* bugs are fixed?  I still see stuff all the time in dup-close dialogs, some tag wiki history IIRC, and whatnot, but every time I've come here and looked someone already reported it first. So at this point (weeks after the debut) I'm just assuming that everything I see has already been reported, until further notice.  I'm very happy that there's a dark mode, but until more fixes start happening maybe the title of this should change to reflect the fact that probably all the things most users will see have already been reported.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not sure what you mean by update? As Aaron fixes things, he adds the status complete tag to the bug report here.

Comment: @Catija: I mean until I see a new meta question, I think most of use are going to assume anything we see is already a known bug because there are so many of them.  When we think they're all fixed, please let us know that so we know it's worth the time to make sure it's reported.  And until then, maybe consider retitling this question that's still pinned in the meta sidebar; it bugs me to see it there every time exhorting me to "help root out" stuff, but that part is basically done and we're more likely to be wasting people's time reporting duplicates than to find new bugs at this point.

Comment: @Catija: I guess a clean fix takes a lot longer to design than just doing some one-off hack for each of the major / frequently-encountered ones, but it's a little frustrating to see the same already-reported bugs every day, along with this enthusiastic question title in the meta sidebar.  (I'm not trying to be grumpy or complain, just explaining why I felt the need to post my first comment... which was half complaint, to be honest.)

Comment: @Catija you guys need to send [Zera](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10046076/zera) a Mug and a Hoodie for his work in maintaining the index :)

Comment: @bad_coder Nah, I'm fine. Also, I'm not staff, so I would be very worried if a mug and a hoodie somehow managed to end up where I live. I sure hope Stack Overflow isn't secretly tracking me .

Comment: 211 answers??? As [someone on the Internet said](https://lbry.tv/@lbry:3f/androidnativenewstuff:4): *"One-third of our users will act like this is Christmas and their birthday rolled into one. The other two-thirds won't care. So we're not going to spend many words on this one. Basically, it's like light mode if you removed all the light."*

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Complete list of reported feature requests and bugs

- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Add toggle button in site switcher ([Zera](/a/395967)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Have different avatars for light mode and dark mode ([Scratte](/a/395979)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Change colours of announcements sidebar ([TylerH](/a/396471) and [JackArbiter](/a/396024)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Make the scrollbar dark ([Eric Silveira](/a/396323)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) Use a colour different to blue/a lighter blue ([Tschallacka](/a/395973), [Makoto](/a/395969), [Markspace](/a/396336) and [Andrew Morton](/a/396205)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) Change colors of visited/non-visited links ([Ahmed Abdelhameed](/a/396862)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) Add colour back to Stack Overflow icon ([TylerH](/a/395992)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Increased contrast on tags and information surrounding questions ([Tschallacka](/a/395973)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Add option to make code block backgrounds black ([akuzminykh](/a/395953)).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Make calendar on profile page dark ([zixuan](/a/396281)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Blue colour of post titles is hard to read ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984) and [Pavel Grishaev](/a/396359)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Question titles and scores are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Timeline event labels are barely readable ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Selected tab text is too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Aaron Christiansen](/a/395960), [Undo ♦](/a/396029), [Sangwin Gawande](/a/395966), [Alirezaaraby](/a/396227), [Nilesh Rathod](/a/396186), [Xymanek](/a/396190), [James says try topanswers.xyz](/a/396062) and [Sangwin Gawande](/a/395966)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Some question titles at `/tools` are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Text fade gradient is still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Sangwin Gawande](/a/395966), [Mazin Ibrahim](/a/396566) and [Luze](/a/396207)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Some buttons on the advertising page have a very little contrast ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Loading post animation is still light ([double-beep](/a/395983) and [Bender the Greatest](/a/396584)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Transparent images can become hard to read ([Alex Telon](/a/396071), [Rahul Wadhwani](/a/396105), [Niyas Nazar](/a/396192), [jcubic](/a/396736) and [gman](/a/396805)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Searching for duplicates is too light and too dark ([double-beep](/a/395986)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Review queue dots imply opposite ([Alconja](/a/396013)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Text is not visible when button is hovered ([Alirezaaraby](/a/396063)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Your edit will be placed in a queue text has poor contrast ([Phoenix](/a/396027) and [Edwin Pratt](/a/396495)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) PluralSight IQ cards are still light ([bravemaster](/a/396112)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Lack of contrast between question highlighting ([Lino](/a/396050)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Badge progress in review queues is still light ([Bernardo Duarte](/a/396261)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Autofill suggestions use a bright background ([wOxxOm](/a/396189)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Vote Synonyms page arrow imperfections ([bad_coder](/a/396771)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Sponsored tag text has lack of contrast ([Luuklag](/a/396616), [Dwhitz](/a/396748) and [D. Pardal](/a/396753)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Silver badge has lack of contrast with expanded profile message ([John Ding](/a/396780)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Question and answer vote, bookmark and timeline buttons are too dark ([Aryan Beezadhur](/a/397388)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Suggested edit queue is full message is too dark ([Aryan Beezadhur](/a/397421)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Text in accepted answer score boxes has lack of contrast ([H.B.](/a/397447)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) This suggestion still needs 1 approve vote message after approving suggested edit has lack of contrast ([Stephan Bauer](/a/398140)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Text is still light when selecting sites in Developer History ([Bernardo Duarte](/a/395987)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Developer Story inputs are too light and too dark ([Ethan Brouwer](/a/396642) and [creyD](/a/396656)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Developer Story gear button is too dark when clicked ([Bizhan](/a/396136)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Developer Story gear dropdown is still light ([Bizhan](/a/396136)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Your recent flag was declined message is too dark ([Aryan Beezadhur](/a/397422)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Newsletter subscription popup is still light ([Mohsin](/a/396312)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Images on privileges page are still light ([Alirezaaraby](/a/396218)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Highlighting code snippets causes lack of contrast ([Rolf ツ](/a/396061) and [Misir Jafarov](/a/397021)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Developer Story page is suddenly ignoring selected theme ([Mazin Ibrahim](/a/396881)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) RSS icon should remain white in the segments ([Daniel A. White](/a/396098)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Bounty and accepted answer score boxes too dark ([H.B.](/a/397447)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Bounty score boxes are inconsistent ([H.B.](/a/397447)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Headers have a lack of contrast ([JDB still remembers Monica](/a/396211)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Stack Overflow for Teams tags are too dark ([Glorfindel](/a/396001) and [Sanjeev Suresh](/a/396113)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Tooltips have not been converted ([bad_coder](/a/396760)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) About page is too bright ([Scratte](/a/395979)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Bold text has lack of contrast ([idclev 463035818](/a/396057)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Pagination controls are too bright ([Sweeper](/a/396065)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Placeholder text has lack of contrast ([bad_coder](/a/396539)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Bounty award text on answers is too dark ([Austin Conlon](/a/397171)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Stack Overflow for Teams feature checklist is too dark ([ADAMJR](/a/397120)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Stack Overflow for Teams boxes are still light ([Mansoor Ahmed Memon](/a/396303)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Decline reason is too dark ([double-beep](/a/395972) and [Bender the Greatest](/a/396719)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Code snippet scroll bars are completely white ([DDriggs00](/a/396360)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Tag badges are still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Compensation calculator is too light and too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Badges have poor contrast ([Luuklag](/a/396003)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Developer Story new item icons are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984) and [Sangwin Gawande](/a/395966)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Consider accepting an answer text is too dark ([mightyteja](/a/396038)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Review queues stats page has too light and too dark text ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Nick](/a/395954), [Syntle](/a/396582) and [bad_coder](/a/396645)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Salary calculator page is still light ([Tomas Crofty](/a/396352)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Imgur image is too dark ([mightyteja](/a/396038)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Job postings offer request Thank You page is still light ([ifnotak](/a/397022)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Titles at `/admin/users` and `/admin/posts` are too dark ([Undo ♦](/a/396029)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Table striping is unusual on multiple `/admin` pages ([Undo ♦](/a/396029)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Job offer panel is still light ([Phoenix](/a/396726)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Profile page flair boxes are still light ([Luuklag](/a/396606)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Job preferences inputs are still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984) and [Aaron Christiansen](/a/395960)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Institutional Investors cards on About page have light images ([Dwhitz](/a/396749)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Tag wiki hyperlink insert modal is still light ([Syntle](/a/397319)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Greyed out link has lack of contrast ([bad_coder](/a/396537)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Suggested edits markdown difference is still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Ronan Boiteau](/a/395999) and [Xymanek](/a/396190)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Next badge modal pagination label is too dark ([Mickael B.](/a/397254)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) My logins page text is too dark and images are not transparent ([Aaron Christiansen](/a/395960)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Stack Overflow for Teams email frequency dialog has contrast issues ([eykanal](/a/396234)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Tour boxes are still light ([VFDan](/a/396217), [zixuan](/a/396643) and [Moritz](/a/396704)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Jobs advertisement is still light ([DeepSpace](/a/395955), [Andrew Truckle](/a/396235) and [zbee](/a/396485)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Inverse text shadow on tour page ([Gus](/a/395971) and [Moritz](/a/396704)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Bar titles in tag top users are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984) and [bad_coder](/a/396551)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) There are new answers text has no background ([VLAZ](/a/395994) and [Nilesh Rathod](/a/396284)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Tag stats are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [mightyteja](/a/396038) and [bad_coder](/a/396441)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Stack Overflow Enterprise contact page is still light ([Gillespie](/a/396653)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Axis and labels text on analytics graphs are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Reputation graph is still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984) and [Makoto](/a/395965)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Watched Tags icon is too bright ([Iter Ator](/a/396246)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Tag filter dialog is still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Alirezaaraby](/a/396056) and [alvin](/a/396732)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Welcome back message is still light ([clickbait](/a/396163), [Xeozim](/a/396399), [Ricardo Boss](/a/396607), [Benjamin Smith](/a/396350) and [Thiago Martins](/a/397006)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Stack Overflow Enterprise statistics are still light ([Thoms_Code](/a/396948)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Code snippet modal is still light ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Some favicons have a lack of contrast ([DwB](/a/396396) and [Jungkook](/a/396912)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Hovered items in products menu are too bright ([retnikt](/a/396371)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Keyboard buttons are still light ([a stone arachnid](/a/396260)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Stack Overflow for Teams images are too dark ([mightyteja](/a/396038)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Editing tag wiki boxes are still light ([mightyteja](/a/396038)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Comment markdown help is still light ([Dave Anderson](/a/396028), [EagleGaming](/a/396329) and [Misir Jafarov](/a/397021)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Site icons are almost invisible ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [binki](/a/396508), [Uni](/a/396048) and [bad_coder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396728/)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Type keywords in code are too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Inline code has low contrast ([bad_coder](/a/395974)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) An edit has been made text has no background ([VLAZ](/a/395991)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Markdown help page and answer markdown help is still light ([double-beep](/a/395980), [Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Scratte](/a/395979) and [retnikt](/a/396371)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Code block syntax highlighting has contrast issues ([jeuxjeux20](/a/396007)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Next badge modal text is too dark ([Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Cássio Renan](/a/395957) and [Jim](/a/396365)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Text in flag/close dialogs is barely readable ([double-beep](/a/395952), [Marco Bonelli](/a/395984), [Abdulla Nilam](/a/396032), [double-beep](/a/395964) and [sashoalm](/a/396278)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Next badge popup is still light ([Macke](/a/395950), [Marco Bonelli](/a/395984) and [hextech](/a/396049)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Text in tooltip on reputation graph is still light ([user7412956](/a/395968)).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Embedded `<iframe>`s should remain white ([Patrick Roberts](/a/395956) and [gman](/a/396515)).

Comment: "Editing tag wiki boxes are still light" has been marked with "status-completed" in this index however, the tag wiki boxes themselves are still light. The reason is probably because the post contains 4 different issues, the specific issue indicated in the title is pending revision.

Comment: Just for my sanity, I'm marking these as `status-completed` as they're merged into `master`. There's sometimes a lag in deployment, so sit tight, y'all. ✌️

Comment: @AaronShekey I think [this one has been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396207) and is status-completed?

Comment: @AaronShekey I think you should make the repository public, just so that I can c̶o̶p̶y̶ ̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶o̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶S̶t̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶O̶v̶e̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w check the changes. 

Comment: @Zera Lemme just get your email so I can add you to my pull requests, hahah 

Comment: @bad_coder Sadly, still exists on Safari. Chrome looks great, which is why I hadn't caught it.

Comment: "Comment markdown help is still light" is definitely not fixed... unless you call [this unreadable mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfZmg.png) "fixed". Seen on Chrome.

Comment: @Nyerguds Sorry for the "unreadable mess". Different markdown help appears in different contexts.

Comment: @AaronShekey There are a few minor, non-duplicate reports that haven't been added to the list yet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397388/10046076, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397421/10046076, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397422/10046076, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397447/10046076. Should I add them?

Comment: @Zera I wonder how you or Aaron are still able to keep track of all this...I thought about adding those new posts but couldn't wrap my head around things anymore.

Comment: It there a way to check the status of these items? I didn't see them in the GitHub repos. I want especially to know when the blue color of the questions will become lighter (big  comfortability issue).

Answer (score 234):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

The Stack Overflow logo at the top of the page should not lose all color just because we're in dark mode:

Normal logo:

[image: normal SO logo in topbar]

New white-washed logo:

[image]

Please consider re-adding at least the orange color to the actual stack overflow icon.

Comment: Awww you beat me:

https://twitter.com/tombyrer/status/1244715846393528321

Comment: Also note: in the footer it's still orange + grey and actually looks fine imo

Comment: It seems I'm only just noticing this now, but it was enough to make me dig up this answer. Please consider changing.

Answer (score 196):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image]

Comment: Came here to post this

Comment: so did I, but it was already here

Comment: `#hireme, .everyonelovesstackoverflow { filter: brightness(0.5); }`

Comment: @TamásBolvári Or `display: none;`...

Comment: Probably a better way to style... `.theme-dark div.clc-jobs-multi>.middle {
    background: #000;
}
.theme-dark div.orange
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(120,51,16) 0%, rgb(122,68,3) 100%);
}`

Comment: I've been using the Dark Reader plugin for chrome to get dark mode for all websites - it works pretty good on most websites.  I like the official dark mode for stackoverflow better then the Dark Reader version except for this ad section, so I went back to using Dark Reader.

Comment: These have been improved on our end and will get deployed soonish. Marking as complete so I don't have to revisit ✌️

Answer (score 183):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

While reviewing suggested edits, here's what clicking 'Reject' looks like:

[image]

"clearly conflicts with author's intent" is invisible.

Also happens with Triage and [Low Quality Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtTsr.png) queues and [flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJAqh.png)/[close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pR25.png) dialogs.

Comment: The edits themselves are also affected. Unchanged text in a changed line is invisible. [Marco](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395984/4518341) mentioned it

Comment: This colouring clearly conflicts with the author's intent. They just didn't want you to know that ;)

Comment: Highlight issue is also relevant for Close Votes (found while closing an issue as Off-Topic, selected close reason cannot be read once highlighted)

Comment: This _should_ be looking better now.

Comment: Just saw a change applied to the close reasons UI a few minutes ago, was that part of the dark mode efforts or something unrelated? I don't remember being able to drag the modal around before, was that just added as well? It's a nice addition in case I need to quickly reference content behind the modal while selecting an option.

Answer (score 118):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Next badge popup

[image]

Also, dark mode is not dark enough for me. :)

Comment: "also, dark mode is not dark enough for me." Challenge accepted.

Comment: Also happens after clicking "Newest" badge.

Comment: @AaronShekey Please don't make the current one darker! Maybe just add a 'midnight' option for those who want things truly black.

Comment: @TylerH perhaps a "none more black" option

Comment: @TylerH There's a big difference between pure black and less bright. I'd personally like a 30% drop in brightness. Perhaps a configurable option would be nice since how black one likes their c̶o̶f̶f̶e̶e  Stack Overflow is something that varies from person to person.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I highly doubt they'll give a configurable slider option, though that would be amazing. I also doubt they'll add *multiple* dark modes with different preset sliders. The best I can hope for is enough people vote up my comment that Aaron sees a significant % of the community doesn't want a too-dark dark mode.

Comment: @TylerH don’t be too concerned. See if you can find one of the two articles that were written about this release... or wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @Catija Thanks :-) Sounds like Aaron and the team had fun with that.

Comment: If you check your preferences, I made the dark mode a little darker for ya ;)

Comment: It's awesome! Please order more black pixels.. :)

Comment: @AaronShekey April Fools!

Comment: @AaronShekey There's a blog post about the making of Dark Mode, but I'd really like to see a post about how the "flashlight" effect in Ultra Dark Mode works.

Comment: @AaronShekey Hey there, I see you made an Ultra Dark Mode but you have made it available only till 5th of April, in the Ultra Dark Mode you have kept the background pitch black whereas in the Dark Mode, it looks like a grey wash. In the Ultra Dark Mode, the pitch black can help people with OLED screens. Also a humble request for a customizable color scheme where one can select the color for links, buttons etc. Hope you take my request into consideration.

Comment: @AaronShekey I feel the ultra dark mode is such a nice playful feature, that it should stay permanently. If it gets to stay or come back later it may be a little more useful if the flashlight would show the light mode instead of a colourless mode. I've been reading several posts on ultra dark mode already, just because it's fun :)

Comment: @AaronShekey Heh. Appreciate flashlight gimmick. But honestly, if the flashlight just covered the entire screen, it'd be perfect for me. :)  ‍

Comment: @AaronShekey You joke but I, er, actually really like that  Can we keep it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm here for the ultra dark mode's background, so if the foreground was light enough to read (kinda like it is in the 'flashlight') I'd be using it right now.

Comment: What is this flashlight and how does one activate it? I can't see anything in Ultra-Dark mode (pun not intended but lovingly embraced).

Comment: @zovits There is no "activating it". It's there in Ultra-Dark, or something's off on your browser/system. [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub2iE.png)

Comment: Looking behind the scenes at how the flashlight effect works one realizes its fairly limited in what it can do (because of the current state of browser css/html capabilities). The flashlight basically takes any amount of colour (any amount of "non-blackness"), and exaggerates it so much that any non-pitch-black colour turns white.

Answer (score 100):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The floating tooltip on the reputation graph has light text in a light box:

[image: low contrast tooltip]

Comment: Came here to post this, glad it's already on the radar

Comment: This should be looking better now. I hope ;)

Comment: Excellent work.

Comment: This bug has been solved

Answer (score 81):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Inverse shadow effect on the "welcome to stack overflow", and "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" text from the tour page:
(http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
[image: stack overflow tour]
I'm calling it a bug instead of just style preference because it hurts my eyes to look at it for some reason.

Comment: Also the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) needs to replace the white images in the examples

Comment: I also figured this. The whole thing should be a bit reworked since the fonts and the examples are quite ... lets say ugly.

Comment: Please tag the answer with `[meta-tag:bug]`.

Answer (score 77):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Add a button in the top right of the sites menu, so that users can toggle between light and dark mode quicker and easier, in case dark mode is causing problems and they need to temporarily switch to light mode.

[image: sites menu]

Comment: This isn't ideal for mobile (I placed the theme toggle next to the site switcher instead of the place circled in your screenshot), but I whipped up [a userscript](https://gist.github.com/patrickroberts/b0c62bddd710f3a3dca5f1d2cadfd678) that does essentially the same thing their code does in the preferences page for themes, if anyone is interested.

Comment: How do I currently turn it off on PC?

Comment: @NelsonGon Profile page -> `Edit profile and settings` -> `Preferences`

Comment: I agree. I like using light modes during the day and dark modes during the night. It's convenient to have a quick toggle button somewhere on the header or footer (rather than having to dig through all sorts of menus).

Comment: @Daniel isn't that what the system setting is for? Configure your OS to switch to dark mode in the evening, and set SO to follow the system

Comment: @andrewtweber The problem is that I prefer to always keep my phone in dark mode.

Comment: I'd like to improve this at some point, but it's not planned just yet. I think getting to preferences in _general_ is way too difficult.

Comment: This should also work when you're not logged in. I've been blinded too many times using someone else's computer, which isn't logged in. If the style was purely CSS, you could even include both and switch between them with the browser. (In firefox, the option is in "View" > "Page Style".) I've seen few sites that do this, I assume for a reason.

Answer (score 74):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Stack Snippet Editor

The embedded snippet result should not render with a dark background. This is a *breaking change* to the look of existing Stack Snippets. See the explanation at the end of this answer and the comment chain below for a detailed explanation of why this shouldn't be implemented like this.

[image: Stack Snippet Editor should not apply dark mode theme to the embedded page]

<sup>[How the Stack Snippet Editor used to look in dark mode theme before the latest patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSIvK.png)</sup>

## Embedded `<iframe>`s(?)

[image: Embedded Stack Snippet should not apply dark mode theme to iframe]

How the embeded stack snippet iframe used to look in dark mode theme before the latest patch:

[image]

Again, this change is a *regression*, see below.

---

### Old answer

#### Possible Solutions?

- Apply the user preference theme to the `<iframe>` if and only if there is no CSS added to the code, either by the `<!-- language: lang-css -->` section, or by `<style>` and `<link>` tags added to the `<!-- language: lang-html -->` section.

**No.** This might seem satisfactory at first, but there are also cases where JavaScript is used to dynamically apply styling, and that would be impractical to account for, since the relevant JavaScript could even be externally linked.

- Apply the user preference theme only if the conditions above are met, and additionally there is no externally linked JavaScript.

**No.** Again, this is still impractical, as statically analyzing the JavaScript for changes to the document styling could potentially leave edge-cases unaccounted for, and any feasible implementation of this would only make the styling for these appear inconsistent *at best*.

- Apply the user preference theme if the only section used is `<!-- language: lang-html -->` and it doesn't contain any `<style>`, `<link>` or `<script>` tags, or `style` attributes [and the approximately 100 deprecated attributes that affect color anywhere].

**No.** This might avoid ruining the contrast for the vast majority of cases ([see below for even *more* exceptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/395956?noredirect=1#comment763687_395956)), but there are so few questions that involve HTML and nothing else, that you'd probably never see this. Why even bother if it's never going to be seen?

**For these reasons, my suggestion is to never apply the user theme to these `<iframe>`s.**

Comment: Regarding the iframe background, there is no need to mess with the iframe's content, it's white because CSS says it should be (`.snippet-box-edit{...background:#fff;...`) By default the document's background is transparent. But dealing with text color might be a problem.

Comment: There's no security risk whatsoever, that line should be removed. It can be easily solved either with some JS appending a link tag, or even with pure CSS.

Comment: The snippet and the iframe "sandbox" in the SO share the same origin, so there's no CORS or any other kind of sharing needed. The "least surprise" has nothing to do with security, it's mentioned in the 3rd topic about confusion.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto then why does `location.origin` in the iframe evaluate to `"https://stacksnippets.net"`?

Comment: You are correct. I always thought they shared the same origin because the iframe has no src attribute. Anyway, they can set the dark theme option in the same way they change the origin. I still can't see how that can be a security risk.

Comment: You can not set the background of the iframe to dark by default. You'll break every example that explicitly set the color of the text to some dark color. You might notice none of the sites like jsfiddle, codepen, codesandbox etc change the color. It's white for that exact reason.

Comment: @gman maybe the condition for when user preference is applied could be based on whether there is any CSS present in the Stack Snippet? Of course that might be asking a bit much, but I think that would at least guarantee it doesn't ruin the contrast of any Stack Snippets.

Comment: @gman on second thought, there may be a handful of cases where Stack Snippets use JavaScript to apply styling, which would be very hard to automatically detect...

Comment: There are other problems than just whether CSS is set by JS. Canvases are transparent and they default to drawing in black so both WebGL and Canvas2D would have issues. PNG files are often transparent. Worse, if you made the iframe switch colors then the dev filling out might mess up and not know it. They might draw/style in white because "works on my machine" only to find out on people in light mode their example is unsuable. Really, it needs to stay white. If you want it dark add CSS to your example.

Comment: @gman I agree with you, see the update to my post

Comment: @gman would an opt-in system be viable in your opinion? A checkbox in the editor below "Hide snippet by default" that says "Apply user theme" could copy `theme-*` classes from the root document body to `stackoverflow-theme-*` classes in the iframe document body (the namespace would be to avoid collisions with potential existing questions that could be using `theme-dark`), and the iframe would contain an additional `<link>` that applies theme-specific styling to the document.

Comment: At that point why not just use an extension?

Comment: @gman because it wouldn't be opt-in per user, it would be opt-in per Stack Snippet. There's a huge difference. This way, the author of the stack snippet explicitly acknowledges that the example is safe to apply whatever the viewer's user theme is.

Comment: Just add a single line `@import 'url/to/your/dark/css';` in your snippet. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/os3pqyav/

Comment: @gman that would match the user's system theme, not the preference they've chosen on Stack Overflow.

Comment: True. Ultimately though I think it would be unsafe to add such an option. Just look at all the bugs on S.O.  I've converted 3 sites to dark mode. It took months to find all the bugs and come up with solutions. They are not all easy especially for images that don't look good over dark background and canvas drawing that need different colors and therefore have to programatically look up the mode and set colors. I think keeping snippet results the default white is best. Giving the option just adds more places for more bugs and broken snippets. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: I think the only true way to deal with this would be to insert js globals, and css classes whose values vary based on the theme set by the current user. This way the coder determining the look of the iframe can take the theme into account, if they are charitable enough to do so.

Comment: So much room for a larger refactor here, but this should much more usable now.

Comment: @AaronShekey thanks for keeping the post updated. I've taken new screenshots to reflect the current status. I don't mean to be difficult about this, but I feel strongly that Stack Overflow should not attempt to apply dark mode theme to the embedded pages themselves.

Comment: Righttt. I'll see what I can do!

Comment: @AaronShekey And I don't mean to downplay the work put into this so far, you guys have done well to knock out these bug reports.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No worries at all. A lot of this CSS is just _so_ global and a bit of a house of cards . I'm on it!

Comment: This should be fixed sometime tomorrow whenever the next build is.

Answer (score 69):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Clicking the question mark button for getting help when posting produces:

[image]

Happens also in comments formatting help (and the [help page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE5Ih.png)):

[image]

In addition, the [Advanced help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) has [related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrKnh.png) [issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVmQe.png) and needs improvement.

Comment: Probably related: the text that says "Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed" has similarly low contrast.

Comment: @CoryCoolguy that issue has been reported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting, this section is barely readable

Comment: **redacted**...

Comment: This should be improved! These pages are generally pretty rough, aren't they. 

Answer (score 61):

Here's some suggestions (click on the first link of each point for a screenshot). **Bold ones** are serious issues. Sorry if the list doesn't really follow some kind of order.

1. [The blue color of post titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYurM.png) definitely feels off for me. I'm having an hard time reading the text. Confront this with [Reddit RES dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y1KB.png) for example.
2. [Question titles and scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW9Lc.png): same here, a bit too dark, they are darker than the question body. I would suggest a simple 100% white. I tested it and it seems perfectly fine IMHO. Question scores also seem too dark in the main page (not only the question page).
3. [Tag badges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnWyV.png): I understand that they are supposed to be different than normal badges, but they stand out *a bit too much* right now. It almost seems like they haven't been styled at all. A different, darker color would be better ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli?tab=badges)).
4. [**Next badge to track dialog**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEi0a.png): wrong text colors, unreadable.
5. [Almost invisible site icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OneMu.png): some kind of background needs to be applied. This affects various parts of the site, and might be pretty hard to get right, but it currently isn't really eye-pleasing.
6. [**Flag modal**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLzS1.png) and [**Close question modal**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ1T3.png): totally unreadable.
7. [Vote event labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhIUB.png) in any post's `/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries` are kind of unreadable ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60603357/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)). I am referring to the blue rectangle with the text "vote" inside. The "answer" labels are also on the edge for me.
8. [**Syntax highlighting**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EioVW.png): type keywords are way too dark ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912892/c-time-in-time-h-updates-its-value-every-128-seconds)), and overall the syntax highlight color scheme is pretty hard to look at. This is most likely not an issue with SO's style itself, but rather with the default syntax highlighter theme that you are using.
9. [Tag stats summary in tag wikis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdYHc.png): unreadable ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info)).
10. [Right bar titles in tag top users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkhlM.png): unreadable ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers)).
11. [**Review queues stats**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plmy5.png): half dark, half light. Unreadable text everywhere ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats)).
12. [Review queue filter dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek8TI.png): still light, also the little title is kind of unreadable ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)).
13. [**Suggested edits markdown diff**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF44b.png): *whelp!*
14. [**Code snippet modal**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jWgp.png): *whelp!* again.
15. [Highlighted code in the Markdown formatting help page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOHR6.png): unreadable ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).
16. [**Tag badge info modals**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynAGn.png): unreadable.
17. [Tab buttons on various pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5r8.png): unreadable. This happens in many places: review queues, `/users`, `/tools`, `/help/badges`, `/help/privileges`, `/site-analytics`, etc.  Some question titles on `/tools` are also [darkened out and hard to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rNPP.png).
18. [Axis and labels text on analytics graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIhUZ.png): unreadable. Both in `/site-analytics` and `/site-analytics/traffic-sources`.
19. [Developer story text fade gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4qa.png): wrong, light color (LOL at this one). Happens [in different places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ORVb.png) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3889449)).
20. [Developer story "add new item" icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2sxK.png): wrong color, invisible.
21. [User profile reputation graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU6XV.png): I don't know if this is intended, but it surely looks odd being all white ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli?tab=reputation&sort=graph)).
22. [Job preferences settings' fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHANs.png): wrong colors, some text is also unreadable (`/users/jobsearch/<user-id>`).
23. You probably already know, but looks like [`/company/compensation/calculator`](https://stackoverflow.com/company/compensation/calculator) is half dark and half light. Bottom text color is also impossible to read.
24. [Some buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeTHG.png) in the `/advertising` website ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/resources/developer-advertising-best-practices)) have very low contrast between text and BG (don't know if this already was a problem, but might as well throw it in there).

Comment: The example you included in nº8, IMO, slightly gained in readability. (Some Dark themes completely change code highlight colors, but thus far SO dark theme kept source code colors very close - which is good.)

Comment: I don't really think so. In which universe is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXKHz.png) more readable than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsRAr.png)? Keyword and non-keyword colors are almost identical, whereas on the light theme keywords are blue and code is black. In the dark theme every color is a pastel color, which does not create a real contrast between keywords and other text.

Comment: @Skeets Light mode: normal text is `#2F3337`, keywords are `#0054A3` => contrast 1.69:1. Dark mode: normal text is `#DADEE0`, keywords are `#B8DFFD` => contrast 1.03:1. I don't think I would ever use such a color scheme. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR1Jq.png) is the theme I use for `vi` and also what I call a good amount of contrast.

Comment: You're comparing colors between themselves, they compare foremost against background. B&W is THE extreme- poor choice example, conductive to eye strain. [**"Too high of color contrast, however, creates a significant disparity in light levels that affect the user's eyes when they read."**](https://uxmovement.com/content/why-you-should-never-use-pure-black-for-text-or-backgrounds/). So far, I think the code block background with source highlights is rather harmonious in this new theme. (I have no intention of elaborating further, given the wealth of your post.)

Comment: @bad_coder yes, I use contrast between the two, because I am talking exactly about that. Contrast between keywords and normal text. The background color has *nothing* to do with my point. I understand your point anyway. Overall, the theme contrast is fine.

Answer (score 57):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

A little bit more contrast would be nice. I really have to focus to read tags and normal info texts that surround questions now.

Chrome also agrees with me. Please use the audit tool in chrome and run a accessibility audit to see which elements need a touch up.

[image: low contrast audit]

Also, can the links be turned into another color than blue? It blends to a strange color that makes my eyes want to turn away on the brown hue on the background.
Setting it to gray(#bbc0c4) is more pleasing and easier to read(for me at least)

[image: linksto gray]

Comment: links other than blue YES PLEASE

Comment: Blue text on dark background in ALWAYS a bad idea!

Comment: IMO, the diarrhea green of the blog/featured section in dark mode ought to just change to the same grey background of the question list.

Comment: The `.started-link` only fails WCAG AAA normal text. The same with [the not so great blue links](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=3CA4FF&bcolor=2D2D2D).

Comment: @double-beep can be, but it's murder on my eyes. And I have pretty good sight. It's harder to focus on te text if it's blue. But that's just a personal experience. Numbers don't say everything

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. I have no idea why but my eyes can't focus on the stack overflow dark mode where as both my editors and the websites I work on all support dark mode and I have no trouble focusing.

Comment: I don't think it is 100% the "blue" that is the issue, I just think it is the saturation of the blue that is being used. My editor uses `#61afef` for blue text and `#2c313c` for the background and it looks fine ([One Dark Pro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhuangtongfa.Material-theme)).

Comment: Yeah, the blue is awful.  I think I'd prefer a slightly yellow-tinged off-white.  Very slightly brighter than the pale grey of the normal text, and just yellowish enough to be clearly identifiable as something different.

Comment: Extra points for the lighthouse screenshot

Answer (score 57):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When reviewing suggested edits as markdown, the text is very difficult to read:

[image: Suggested edit review]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25729138

Comment: I fixed this at some point but honestly have no memory of doing so, hah.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the meaning of the 'status-completed' tag, but this is still a problem @AaronShekey. At least on the Review Suggested Edits page on StackOverflow. Using Chrome 83.0.4103.61.

Comment: Looks like this in both Safari and Chrome  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqon6.png @MeanGreen

Comment: @AaronShekey I can confirm that it still looks as shown in the bug report. I'm using Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61 as well (latest version at time of writing). https://imgur.com/QUBm9vC

Comment: Got it. The `markdown` page, _not_ the `rendered output` page. Fix is in!

Comment: Still an issue and making me `skip` all these.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Can you send a link to a page where you still have this issue? The link from the post above looks fine for me.

Comment: Now that you mention it it's suddenly gone. Wtf?

Answer (score 44):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Extending double-beeps answer. A lot of information of review queue summaries is either too hard or impossible to read. Notably the tabs text in the top right, the review count labels and the text in the yellow box linking to the queue.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed and upvoted.

Answer (score 44):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Loading a post in the [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) or [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) queues produces:

[image]

It should maybe look like when loading an answer outside of a queue:

[image]

Comment: ..also on the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: For me it means that for 2-3 seconds on each review task I cannot read the post due to the animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VingF.gif

Comment: Looks like they're still using the animation for white. It's this way in all queues.

Comment: This _is_ a major one. My eyes started hurting after skipping 3 or 4 posts.

Comment: Literally going back to light theme because reviewing with dark theme is nauseating. @double-beep pls remove "(not a major one)" from the post

Answer (score 38):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The contrast ratio of the decline reason is 1.25:1 ([fails all WCAG text standards](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=800000&bcolor=2D2D2D)):

[image]

Comment: oh man, if we're going to get WCAG involved, I imagine there's a lot of places on the site that would fail in Dark Mode right now.

Comment: It's pretty safe to assume that this isn't an intentional choice, merely an oversight... it's... headache-inducing to know about how many manual overrides and hard coded things there are. :) No need to bring WCAG into it. :D

Comment: @Catija this one (and the other I reported before) are the ones hurting more my eyes :)

Comment: @Catija You can reassure yourself by knowing that when this is done, there will be less of that (unless your programmers start hardcoding for light and dark mode).

Comment: Well, if the WCAG standards are used to begin with, many of these bug reports would not be happening; IE:  what may look fine to one programmer may be hard to read for another programmer with a different monitor, etc. etc...

Answer (score 36):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: Welcome back!]

The welcome back message has low-contrast text

Comment: I hate the welcome-back message anyway. I say get rid of it.

Answer (score 34):

Transparent images uploaded by users can be difficult to read.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46876752/1723886) question there are two images.
[image]

The top image seems to be transparent and so it looks good without dark mode:

[image]

Examples of this issue found by other users. The solution for this issue should should work well for these situations too.
[Niyas Nazar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396192/1723886) found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) where uml arrows are hard to read in dark mode.
[Rahul Wadhwani](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396105/1723886) found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945193/average-runtime-of-quickselect/25796762#25796762) where images of equations are hard to read.

Comment: You only want to swap the black/whites, not the hue of the color, as people might refer to the purple line or the green line in a line chart

Comment: @Ferrybig actually, a white outline on the black text/lines is also going to fix it. But then again, that relies on the image being generated that way.

Comment: @Ferrybig People could also refer to a black line in a line chart though, right? I feel like it would take an AGI to figure out how the image intended for bright mode should look in dark mode... And don't forget the dark mode people who might create an image that looks good on dark mode, but looks terrible on bright mode. I suggest that every transparent pixel is replaced with white or black, depending on the uploader's preference.

Comment: I suggest `Transparent == White`. That was true before and I think that should be true even with dark mode. That way there will never be any confusion regarding the colors. People will have to live with white images in dark mode anyways. Adding the default white background behind images should ensure that images always looks like intended.

Comment: Making sure the image always looks the same is probably very important for discussions about colorblindness and other topics specifically about colors. I think the images in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57153428/1723886) should look the same even if they would have been transparent. When the images were posted they users did not know that it would make a difference if the image was transparent or white. So it seems the safe choice is to force transparent to be white.

Comment: A white background may be added for images in dark mode to look the same for all the old questions and the new ones too.

Comment: @AlexTelon When forcing the images to turn white, we shouldn't do that by modifying the actual images themselves, in certain cases the transparency is required or wanted, for example when you need to upload an image o you can use it in your code snippet

Comment: @Ferrybig I can see that I was a bit unclear. I meant `Transparent == White` not as something to be done on the image, but as the effect the user should see. Transparent has looked like white before and should continue to do so. I suggested adding the default background behind images.

Comment: @Alex_Telon Yes there should be a white background by default behind old posts having transparent images. There should also be a way for users who really want transparency on the dark background to override the default.

Comment: @PaulRougieux What problem would this solve? If a user wants a black background they can always edit the image not to be transparent.

Comment: @AlexTelon I guess there can be cases - plots are an example - where a red curve on transparent background would be perfectly fine both with white background and dark background. In this case no need to add the white background. But in most other cases, it's better to have a white back ground under transparent images in dark mode.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254869/bezier-cubic-curves-moving-with-uniform-acceleration)'s another one I found.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/531/8326775)

Comment: At the risk of example overload I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/6472082 which led me to this post.

Comment: On, for example, https://newegg.com, in the dark theme, images have a light-grey background so they remain white and readable, but at least somewhat retain the purpose of a dark theme.

Answer (score 29):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

All of the links on a given page look a little too *blue*.  Don't get me wrong; blue is my favorite color.

But seeing it like this, kind of everywhere, does still grate the vision a little bit.  A different shade for dark mode links would be ideal.

[image]

Comment: Disagree w/ this one; I think the links look way better against the dark background now than they ever did w/ the white background.

Comment: a lighter blue would go a long way

Comment: I agree with this; the SO dark theme has the same problem most dark themes have; too much blue-against-black.

Comment: Agree -- the blue is very tough on the eyes. I think a light green would be easy on the eyes!

Comment: @theforestecologist:  [That could *easily* run afoul of the people who are selectively color blind](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/types-of-colour-blindness/).  All I know is that this is a bit much, and I'd like it to change, but I don't want to prescribe a new shade that violates WCAG.

Comment: @Makoto fair. though I was thinking *very* light green -- as in nearly white, but a little less starkly contrasted than white. Though, the greys/whites seen on the [preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/) when I select dark mode are fine. I don't see a need to make titles stand out more from these links.

Answer (score 28):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Searching for dupes is broken:

[image]

Vote count is not shown and the contrast of small letters is too low.

Comment: The initial dup-close popup is not great either; light-gray small text on a medium-gray background

Answer (score 25):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the "Select your next badge" modal, there is text that isn't very visible:

[image]

Comment: This got switched to a new component and should be looking a lot better.

Comment: Thank you, sir :D. It does look better, indeed.

Comment: @AaronShekey I noticed badge order has been inverted. Looking at the screen shot Bronze was at the left hand side, whereas now Gold is at the left most...Not saying I dislike it, but usual western writing is left to right, and so progression would intuitively follow that order. In a strange sort of way I find the change rather refreshing...

Answer (score 21):

This looks really awesome overall! A fantastic addition to the site :)

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

*Job Preferences* under *Edit Profile and Settings* still has some light-theme fields:

[image]

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The *My Logins* page under *Edit Profile and Settings* still has some dark text and non-transparent icons:

[image]

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The hover and selection colours of the tabs in [*Privileges* in the *Help Center*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) still behave as in light theme:

[image]

The [*Badges*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page has the same issue.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The time range selector in [*Users*](https://stackoverflow.com/users) still uses dark text:

[image]

Comment: Came here to post about the My Logins issue.

Comment: Wish I had more upvotes! It has been two weeks and none of them are fixed.

Answer (score 18):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The code block syntax highlighting has some contrast issues:

[image: Contrast: 2.98]

Comment: Also this is even worse with a blue light filter on :(

Comment: I don't think this is related to C# in particular. It's the code highlighting in general. It is the same in C and PowerShell.

Comment: @LWChris oh yeah you're right, updated it

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my answer that was a duplicate of this. I somehow overlooked this when searching for the issue. I think it appeared to me as if it was about links.

Comment: I made that color lighter in dark mode. Hopefully it's a bit more readable now.

Comment: Yeah it's definitively better now, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The text is barely visible.

[image]

Text not visible (CTRL+G )
[image]

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Image not apt to the background
[image]

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Editing Tag wiki

[image]

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Tag Info Page

[image]

Comment: Please post the general bug as a separate question

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) [stack-overflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

While I can read main site tags without much trouble, Teams tags are much harder to read because of the lack of contrast:

[image]

Comment: Yeah. It's going to take some finesse. Some of the theme color options for Teams work just great, others are a little hard to discern. :)

Comment: Your tags look much better than ours - did you change any settings from their defaults?

Comment: @gordy might be a browser difference? I'm using Firefox on macOS. I agree your screenshot is better, I'll delete mine.

Comment: turns out you can change this. it's "Theme color" in the team settings

Comment: @gordy thanks, didn't know about that since I'm not a team admin.

Comment: This is by far the biggest problem for me. Maybe it's because I'm red-green colorblind and our tags are `#9a3324`, but the first time I logged into Teams I literally thought the tags were missing until I looked closer.

Comment: Tags have now a lighter colour - status-completed?

Comment: @double-beep nothing has changed for me (I still see the same thing as in the [first revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/396001/revisions)). As mentioned above, it will depend on the Teams settings.

Comment: Yeah, so these tag colors are themed based on the Team administrator's color choices. We don't have a great way of automatically adjusting someone's branded colors to something that makes sense on dark mode. Internal discussions have lead us to reconsider theming tags at all. We're looking at it 

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Reputation graph still shows up with a white background.  Likely due to the fact that it's a generated image; perhaps this shouldn't be the case anymore?

[image]

Comment: It's an svg, not an image, so it should be simple enough to style the elements of it

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I think dark mode is excellent.

Only problem I have noticed is insufficient contrast with inline code. (The difference in fonts is good, but the difference in background contrast could be more crisp.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: This should be improved a little bit in the next build. I made the background color on those `code` blocks a little darker. I think there's a larger project of examine our font and line-height choices.

Answer (score 12):

Update : 2

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
In **Review Suggested Edits** :

Review Tab not visible :  [image: Review Tab not visible]

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

History Tab hover also not proper : [image: History Tab hover also not proper]

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**1. Adding the Developer Story. Icons seems to be too dark.**

[image: Icons seems to be too dark]

**2. Personal Statement section goes beyond limit.**

Read More Screen :
[image: Read More Screen here]

Read Less Screen :
[image: Read Less Screen]

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

**3. Story tab text is too dark.**

[image: Story Tab text]

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Story tab hover:

[image: Story tab hover]

Comment: That one white badge *should* be a different colour, it's a tag badge

Comment: @aaronshekey Regression on issue 0 in this list: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398799/election-tabs-arent-fully-covered-by-dark-theme

Answer (score 12):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

The [about](https://stackoverflow.com/company) page is a little harsh on the eyes, once they've adjusted to the Dark mode:

[image]

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Not enough contrast between the white and the light gray in the examples on the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#italics-bold) page. I then realized this is also mentioned in [double-beep's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395980/12695027) but leaving the screenshot:

[image]

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

A double avatar option. One that goes on other users dark mode and another that goes on users light one.

Comment: [Apparently ninja'd](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395980) :)

Comment: @double-beep I just noticed. Feel free to edit the screenshot out into your own post :)

Comment: The double avatar situation is actually pretty complicated. We'd need to store all those images. We'd also have to figure out how to integrate with gravatar, and split the UI to upload an image for each context? Seems gnarly.

Comment: @AaronShekey I find it absolutely awesome that I happened to find a great feature-request that seems so simple, but turns out to be unfeasible :) Thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The icon color of both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow doesn't change. This can be seen when going to your profile menu when you are about to log out or switch community.

[image]

Comment: From the question: "Site sprites (appear in the site switcher or on profile pages) haven't been adapted to the dark theming. This means sites icons with dark colors (e.g. Super User, U&L, Salesforce, Wordpress, etc) may be difficult to see. "

Comment: I suspect this also relates to the MSO icon in the featured questions box.

Answer (score 12):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Bold text isn't as bold anymore. I mean if I know what to look for I can see it, but that isn't the purpose of making something **bold**.

In the original theme **bold text** stands out from the rest of the text, but hard to spot the difference here:

[image]

For comparison, similar text in light[image]

Even with the small screenshots, in the light theme, the bold text clearly stands out, while in the dark theme also a bigger image won't change much.

**PS** I hope it is also fine to leave positive feedback... I love that orange:

[image]

Please don't change it!

Comment: Could you include the bold example in white-theme underneath for "side-by-side" comparison?

Comment: @bad_coder it is randomly generated Lorem ipsum, but I can add something similar

Comment: I mean the exact same text, but in both themes, for exact visual comparison.

Comment: @bad_coder there you go

Comment: This is my frustration with dark modes in general, the contrast just isn't nearly as usable. I won't be able to fix this with color alone. Looks like font choice and line height will do it. Deferring for a larger look.

Comment: @AaronShekey you could love some guys just [for their noirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh#/media/File:Van-willem-vincent-gogh-die-kartoffelesser-03850.jpg).

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

After suggesting an edit, here's what happens

[image: Edit]

The contrast should be adjusted, because it is difficult to see.

Answer (score 10):

In Developer History, when setting personal info.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Missing background of **An edit has been made to this post** text/button:

[image]

I cannot give a link to a page, as it's every post and you need to have already opened a question and wait for somebody to make an edit to see this.

[Also see **X new answers to this question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395994/3689450)

Comment: This should be fixed in the next build. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- Headers on [/admin/users](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/users) and [/admin/posts](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts):

  [image]
- Tables, as you say - but [/admin/find-users](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/find-users?q=foo) has some unique artifacts in the table striping.
- [/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic?deactivated=1](//stackoverflow.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic?deactivated=1) doesn't use tables, but does have the same white-on-white effect.
- Tabs on [/annotated-posts](//stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts) are a bit off:

  [image]

  And turns white on hover:

  [image]

Comment: Wow, the find users page is like Beetlejuice!

Comment: Note: The same issue exists on [Help Center > Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4FQj.png))

Comment: Cracked open a pull request to fix these today. Should get merged after the long holiday weekend.

Answer (score 10):

I think this image can be another bug in the dark mode because the button's text is not showing when the mouse pointer enters the button.

In the Profile Activity > BADGES when a new badge everyone earns the button's text of congratulations dialog not show.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Minor one, but the review queue icons now seem to imply the empty queues are the most important:

`v Current light v`
[image: Current light]

`v Current dark v                       v Suggested dark v`
[image: Current dark]
[image: Suggested dark]

Comment: Technically, the grey dot means there's only a few tasks, not that they're empty. If they're empty, they don't have a dot at all. :) That said, your suggestion makes sense. Maybe a bit lighter but... :)

Comment: @Catija May I suggest red - orange (not yellow) - greenish?

Comment: @Scratte Using colors rather than shading or greyscale vs single color (or other sorts of choices), they're not noticeably different to people who have colorblindness - particularly red vs green, which is the most common variety.

Answer (score 9):

Bugs

**On Click (Close Vote screen)**
[image]

---

**On Hover(Close Vote screen)**

[image]

---

Comment: I appreciate this! I think that some of these have already been reported. Could you remove any that are already here? I know it's long and hard to look through but it's probably easier for you to do than me - for example, the last one you posted is the second-higest-scoring answer here. Thanks :D

Comment: @Catija sure will do

Comment: All of these have been reported: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395952, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395986.

Comment: @double-beep I thought so too, but the first one looks very different. Much less text is lost in the link you posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395952

Answer (score 9):

PluralSight IQ cards are not showing very well.

[image]

Comment: Gotta work on those Java skills, buddy :))

Comment: @oamandawi Thanks, dude. This could be a lifetime tip. xD

Answer (score 8):

IMO, the difference, between questions which are highlighted, ignored or normal (in that order in the screenshot) is to minimal:
[image]

The same image but in light mode is far more distinguishable, because highlighted questions have a different colored background
[image]

Comment: Agree on the ignored questions, but highlighted seem fine to me

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Found another example of the bug related to inverse shadow, it is not working well with formulas.

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945193/average-runtime-of-quickselect]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796762/1723886) is a link to the post you found. Those are in fact transparent images. So this seems to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396071/1723886.

Comment: If there is a duplicate issue present should I let this post be here or delete it?

Comment: I'm new here too so don't know either. The other post is mine so I don't want to be the one telling you that you should remove yours in favor of mine in case that is not the way to deal with things here.

Comment: I think I will just leave it as another example

Answer (score 8):

Have you given thought to your adverts area? These are white and quite contrasting.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In the Tag "watching & ignoring" at "Ignored Tags" section the autofill textbox for adding new tags is white and suggested tags not showing like below picture:

[image]

Comment: This one has been reported already.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Missing background to **X new answers to this question**

[image]

Very similar to [the my other bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395991/) - I cannot give a link to a page, since it's every question and you have to open it and wait for an answer to be posted.

Answer (score 6):

Can the background of badges get some more contrast, the boxes are almost invisible, especially when compared to the background of tags.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

### Selecting code snippets in dark mode:

*Especially keywords seem to cause problems.*

[image: code selection in dark mode]

Comment: This is super tricky, and I don't think Stack Overflow should be too opinionated here. This can be adjusted system-wide, and I think we should respect that. I think! For now. 

Answer (score 6):

Overall, great job by everyone!

Some minor stuff:

1. This format for bug reports kinda sucks.  Don't you have a regular bug base for this?  (This format = everyone just post a bunch of answers to a question.  Seems iffy and a dedicated search function would be handy too.)
2. The main text on the main page is bright white, 100%. (Well, it's rgb(231, 232, 235) according to FireFox, but it's still pretty bright.)  I'd like to see something just a bit dimmer, like 40% or so.  Usually dark themes like this have grayer text.
3. Ditto for links, like the titles of questions on the main page.  They're bright blue (looks like the default blue), they could be a bit dimmer or darker.
4. User default icons have white backgrounds, these could be changed to something darker, like the background color of the theme (or transparent so the work for both?)
5. Once Dark Mode is selected, I'd like to see it on all my accounts, including this page (meta.stackoverflow.com) and all my stackexchange.com accounts.  Yeah I know probably a lot more work.
6. This page: https://stackoverflow.com/company has a super bright blue header.  Could be a bit dimmer.

This seems like a long list now, I'll stop.  Thanks again for the great work!

Comment: #5 is explained in the OP: "For now, this is Stack Overflow in English only at this point - it doesn’t even work on MSO currently." It's a beta, relax :). Many of the other items in your list have already been mentioned in other answers. Please search for those an remove the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to other message pop ups I've seen reported, the "Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up." message is has unreadable contrast.

[image]

This page: [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: This has already been reported here in another answer, FYI

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396163

Answer (score 6):

Some of the HNQ icons are wrong, for example the Japanese Stack Exchange icon is rendered as the 3d printing meta icon. I'm using Firefox 75.0 on a Windows 10 system, and have reloaded the page with caches disabled. Other users report that the icons are correct in light mode.

I haven't noticed other icons that are off yet.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed. Hmmm. Interesting one.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The markdown examples in the help text for adding a comment are hard to read. Font color should be white.

[image]

Comment: This has be reported, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395980 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395979.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)

The question feed RSS icon should remain white in the segments. The segments are hollow so the background color shines thru.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The background in the tour is white, but the text is gray

[image: the bug]

Answer (score 5):

On Teams sites, after clicking on a tag, a popup comes up asking whether the user wants email notifications. Some issues there:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In review queues when checking badge progress.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed that the information box that says:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and hyperlinks.

It seems a bit hard to see when editing an answer/question while in dark mode. And it may make new users a bit confused if they are not used to the editing process...

I have added an image to help out.

[image: The light background and grey text makes it harder to see the information box.]

Comment: The edited post title also has bad contrast ("Creating a java library...", black text)

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The contrast in action description text in close/flag/review actions dialogs [fails all WCAG standards](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=6A737C&bcolor=4A4E51):

[image]

Comment: Contrast has now been increased and [looks OK now](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=ACB2B8&bcolor=2D2D2D). Thanks SE!

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? Or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? Or maybe just a nitpick... I don't know.

Pagination controls' selected color is too bright. They stand out *too* much. The contrast between the white text and orange background is also a bit too little:

[image]

I just realised it doesn't look as bad as it actually is on the screenshot, because it's against the white background of meta.

Comment: My least favorite tag, but yeah, these are as intended. We might be able to drop that down a brightness level, but all the things like this use the same color, and we'd have to change it in every context. 

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear to me what "system mode" means. On Linux, I don't know of any such setting. On Android 10+, it doesn't seem to respect the "dark mode" setting:

[image]

*Edit:*

Indeed, when selecting the *full site* (as opposed to the default mobile view above, it does respect the Android system setting

[image]

Comment: It depends on the operative system and browser support. Also, in the screenshot you show you are not viewing the responsive version, but the "mobile" site. Scroll down to the bottom and click on "full site". Dark mode is not available on the mobile site, only in the responsive version.

Comment: My guess is that they are looking at the ["prefers-color-scheme"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) css property, a demo: https://codepen.io/svoisen/pen/VRegLe

Comment: Dark mode was added in Android 10, wasn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Makes one wonder why there is a dedicated mobile site at all.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I don't think it's actually that dedicated anymore. The design of SO for a while now has been moving more and more toward a responsive "one site for all devices" design.

Comment: "System default" does not detect GNOME theme, although as noted above, this is probably an issue with prefers-color-scheme and WebKit/Blink. I have "Adwaita-dark" set  as Themes>Applications in GNOME Tweaks (as opposed to "Adwaita _(default)_"), but prefers-color-scheme is still "light", despite that Chrome is using dark color in title and bookmarks bar already.

Comment: Turns out, on Linux, the issue is Chromium-only (affects Google Chrome, Electron etc.), see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903. Mozilla Firefox works just fine.

Comment: I don't understand why the deprecated mobile site is still the default.

Comment: Still so many mobile layouts to convert to responsive. This might be my next big initiative here.

Answer (score 4):

Just now I started to face a new issue when I tried to access *Developer Story* *inside* my Stack Overflow profile after switching from the *activity* tab:

Activity Tab:

[image]

Developer Story tab:

[image]

This is happening while I'm still on the dark theme; please check this. Maybe a small bug while trying to fix the theme.

Comment: We've opted the page out for now since there's a ton of work left.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

As one of the purposes of a dark-theme is high contrast, I'd like to have the *option* to display the background of code blocks black, i.e. `#000000`. (Maybe a checkbox in the preferences?)

[image: default]
[image: daaaark]

Comment: I would wait for this to be out of beta to start requesting new features.

Comment: "wait for this to be out of beta" != "make a new question about it right now"

Comment: And posting a separate question with this feature request at this stage would be premature, and correctly closed as a dupe since this Q&A would show you that the feature is still in beta and not yet ready for new feature requests. "Pathetic", "brainless"... I don't know why do you feel the need to resort to that language, but I would tone it down.

Comment: @yivi I understand the *"at this stage would be premature"* but this is not a duplicate. Because the feature is still in beta, this is a duplication of the main post that is about finding bugs and *low-contrast and un-converted bits*? What? I think this feature would be a great addition to the site and I just want to post it so it's already on the table - exactly what a feature-request should be like. Things can be planned much better when potential features are known early.

Answer (score 3):

Developer Story - Edit button (gear icon) is too dark when in MouseOver state and also its pop-up color is bright

OK:

[image]

Not OK:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Autofill suggestions are using a bright background at least in Chrome:

1. start editing a post
2. click the "Edit Summary" input
3. when the autofill menu appears press the down arrow key to select an item in that menu

[image: bad]

**StackOverflow Dark** usercss style solved [this issue](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark/issues/123) via an animation hack:

```
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
  to {
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: none;
    color: #ddd;
  }
}
input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover, textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill !important;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both !important;
}
```

With this fix applied:

[image: good]

Comment: I've filed this as an issue on Stacks. It'll get fixed on the design system side. Nice catch! https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/502

Answer (score 3):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Headers in posts don't stand out very well in dark mode.

In light mode, the bold black text really pops out and helps to visually "break up" a long post. But in dark mode, the brightness of the regular body text seems to match the headers and they get drowned out, making it harder to distinguish sections.

This might just be my eyes, but on long posts I have to search a lot harder for the headings.

I have screenshots below, but you can try it for yourself on this post:

[Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers/12643073#12643073)

### Light Mode

> [image]

### Dark Mode

> [image]

Here is another screenshot of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605454/642706) shown side-by-side, in dark and light modes. Scanning for the headings is easier in light mode.

[image: screenshot of two pages side-by-side, one in dark mode, the other in light mode]

Comment: This super tough, and something that's a real problem on dark modes in general. Ideally we'd be able to change our font stack to include more weights. This article really sums up the issue https://css-tricks.com/dark-mode-and-variable-fonts/

Comment: @AaronShekey - Thanks for the reply. That article is very interesting! Yeah, I figured it wasn't an easy fix. Additional decorations, like underlining, would also not be ideal.

Comment: It's a long goal of mine to replace Arial with something with more rendering flexibility. But, we're a lean company with a ton of traffic. We don't want to just force everyone to load a ton of fonts. Tough one!

Answer (score 3):

In the users menu at the left of the screen, the text's of buttons for the filter is not visible when they are select.

like:

[image: sample one]

and

[image: sample two]

Comment: This has already been reported.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/teams

I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature but while surveying the beta dark-mode, I came through this.

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

By clicking the sidebar widget of the newsletter subscription, it opens a popup with a white background.

---

**Screenshots**:

**1)** [image: Newsletter Widget]
**2)** [image: Popup with White Background]

---

To reproduce the issue:

- Visit any question and look at the widgets on the right side.
- In between **"Featured on Meta"** and **"Linked"** or **"Related"** portion you might find this widget. Refer 1st screenshot.
- Click on **see an example newsletter**.
- It'd open a popup with a white background. Refer 2nd screenshot.

---

> **NOTE:** You won't see any **weekly newsletter** widget if you're already subscribed.

---

I hope it helps.

Comment: It's not ideal, but our emails aren't dark-mode enabled. That preview is accurate, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

@Marco-Bonelli [mentions this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395984/10794031), but no screen shot was included. For completeness:

**Stats on the Tag Info page are difficult to read.** [E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Looking for a Job?" item in the sidebar is not converted, though components of it are (the tags for the job's languages).

[image]

Comment: First post to mention the components in ads. Ads by themselves had been mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396235), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395955).

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems like dark mode was mistakenly added to the **result** of snippets.

Snippet results can not be auto-dark mode. Otherwise, they'll break 1000s of snippet on this site. Example:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
for (let i = 10; i < 70; i += 10) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.beginPath(); ctx.arc(75, 75, i, 0, Math.PI * 2); ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<table style="text-align: center;"><tr>
  <td>Some <span style="black">black</span> text</td>
  <td>
    <div>a canvas</div>
    <canvas width="150" height="150"></canvas>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>an image</div>
    <img src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/resources/scene-down.svg" width="200">
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

ends up like this in dark mode

[image]

Users can't be expected to test light and dark modes in their snippets. All the major live coding sites came to this conclusion. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen), [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), etc. all default to the default (white) in their results panels because anything else is guaranteed to make things unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In your profile **if you don't have any network communities visible** the link "View Network profile" has a different color of blue.

It's probably supposed to be "greyed out", however just a glance at it strains the eyes because of low contrast. The screen shot has two side-by-side examples for comparison. Please notice the problem is worst on-screen, because fonts are smaller.

(It's also the only instance of this color I recall seeing on the site.)

[image]

Comment: FYI this one isn't a duplicate, I checked.

Comment: This one's coming in a build or two. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I noticed on the Developer Story tab when using story mode, there's a white line on the lower end of education information when it's long enough to cause a `read more` text button to appear:

[image: When info is minimized]

But it disappears after expansion:

[image: When info is expanded]

Comment: I have the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/5897829

Answer (score 3):

[I managed to take a video of this issue](https://youtu.be/r_xA1eq0Hig), but in the review queue, when the subject matter highlights right after loading up the item for review, it flashes white instead of using a darker accent to draw attention to the space. It causes the highlight to flash and distract from the content of the page, and makes the underlying text difficult to read briefly.

Comment: I support this, the **question** below the answer being reviewed has especially low contrast. (It's also faded in light-theme but for some reason I find it harder to read in dark theme.)

Comment: I think part of it is having that bright splash of bright white flash on your dark screen in a dark room making your eyes bleed is what does it for me.

Comment: I was just in the review-queues, and the "flash" also makes you loose a couple of seconds before it lets you see the post. Taken over, say, 50 reviews/day that's 1min30sec looking at the same animation...The animation also gets old in less than 20 reviews for me...(I share your thought about the "flash", it does cause me daze.)

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: Jobs]

This job offer panel is difficult to read, especially with the silver (I think) text.

Comment: I believe this one was fixed, and should be out in the next build or... two :)

Answer (score 3):

Silver badge cannot be seen clearly in expanded profile message.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links

I'm not a UX expert but in my experience, visited links are usually styled with a "more dull" color. With this new dark mode, it seems the be quite the opposite. Here are some examples:

**Home Page:**

[image: Home Page]

**Sidebar:**

[image: Sidebar]

**Profile Activity** (Votes, Responses, All actions):<sup>*</sup>

[image: Profile Activity tabs]

In all the examples above, it's always the "brighter color" that is used to indicate visited links and the "more dull" color is used to indicate non-visited links. That seems counter-intuitive to me and I'm mistaking them all the time. I think it's more obvious in the second and third examples. I used to immediately spot newly featured Meta posts that I haven't visited. Well, not anymore.

<sub>P.S. I posted this as a discussion [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396792/8967612) a few days ago. I will probably delete it or close it as dup soon.</sub>

---

<sub>(Feel free to skip this part)</sub>

<sub>For comparison, this is how it looked like with a Chrome extension that I used before the SO Dark Mode was released:</sub>

[image: Home Page using a Chrome extension]

<sub>..and this is how Reddit, for example, handles visited links in dark mode:</sub>

[image: Reddit]

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>There's also the inconsistency issue with this one. It uses this styling only for the last 3 tabs (under Profile > Activity). The remaining tabs use the same styling that's used for the Home Page.</sub>

Comment: This post is really cool. I had noticed these issues but didn't want to bring them up without doing a good job, which you did.

Comment: @bad_coder If you think it's a good suggestion, upvoting the answer may give it a better chance of being taken into consideration.

Comment: I was the only guy that up voted it.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one with this issue,. I don't think I've ever seen a lighter "visited" link before, it's definitely not standard

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: text dark]

https://stackoverflow.com/teams

The text is dark and difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

**Text color of the infobox is hard to read (after approving a suggested edit)**

When approcing a suggested edit that needs more approves, an infobox with the following text is shown:

> This suggestion still needs 1 approve vote from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue.

The color of the text is set to `#990000` which is hard to read on dark background (`#2D2D2D`)
[That's a Contrast Ratio of **1.54:1**](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=990000&bcolor=2D2D2D)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

[image: Tags]

Internal tags selection seem to be unreadable with the new color contrast. The tags in the list view are also not readable.

Comment: Duplicate, check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396001.

Comment: Added a comment on the original there. It's tricky, and we might bail on theming tags since admins can choose colors that make no sense in dark mode.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25748973

- Active tab top-right

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- Code block

[image]

Comment: Duplicate, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395999.

Comment: ok, will not try to help then. Also, the one you linked doesn't include my first point ("Active tab top-right")

Comment: If you scroll through the answers, you'll find similar issues that have been reported.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The icon for the "Watched Tags" suggestion is white.

[image: Watched tags]

Comment: If it was black, then it would not be seen because it would blend in with the black outside of it,

Comment: I did not say that is should be black. I suggest that instead of a bright white circle, it should look a bit different.

Comment: What "different"?

Comment: I don't know, I am not a designer. I just feel that this icon does not look good in the dark mode.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The `<kbd>` tag is too light:

[image: keyboard tag too light]

Comment: And it is too dark if the content is a code block: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898070/2625561

Comment: This should look better after the next build. Thanks for finding it!

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Code-box scroll bars are completely white, with no way of telling what position it is in:

Dark theme example:
[image: Example image Dark theme]

Light Theme Example:
[image: Example image light theme]

here's a live example

```
// this is a really long line of code this is a really long line of code this is a really long line of code this is a really long line of code
```

Note: This affects vertical scroll bars in addition to horizontal ones

I am using Firefox 75.0 on Kubuntu 18.04

Edit: This appears to be fixed

Comment: Which browser and operating system are you using? Having trouble reproducing this bug.

Comment: @AaronShekey I am using Firefox 75.0 on Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The *[WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)* and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour) favicons are very low contrast in dark mode.
The classes are:

```
class="favicon favicon-wordpress"
class="favicon favicon-mathoverflow"
```

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

On the "Ask Question" page.

Both *Tags* and title boxes have a low contrast pre-filled text.

(For comparison, the search box pre-filled text has a slightly different color.)

**Edit:** Arguably this isn't a bug, and low contrast is intended. The same happens in **most** (**but not all**) pre-filled textboxes; in light-mode faded grey is used. The *Add Comment* box is another notable example.

[image]

Comment: FYI this one isn't a duplicate, I checked.

Comment: This one is by design, but could be improved. Punting!

Answer (score 2):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

"Synonyms" and "Related Tags" headings are too dark, in both [Synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/synonyms) and [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers). However, both are rendered differently in [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info).

[image]

Comment: FYI this one isn't a duplicate, I checked.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [`suggested-edits`'s stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) page seems to have *uncovered bits*.

[image: Screenshot from https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats]

Comment: Pushed some improvements here. Should merge in and get deployed after the long holiday weekend.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: "Please upvote" Message]

This popover asking you to upvote the question has a bright background and a fairly light font color. I would consider making it a bit darker.

Comment: Already reported: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396163/10046076.

Comment: @Zera correct me if I'm wrong: this exact instance has not been reported, has it?

Comment: The messages appear to be exactly the same. They are both welcome back messages and have the same message. If there is a difference, please could you point it out.

Comment: @zera Sorry, you appear to be correct. Looks like I didn't see the answer when I first clicked on the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is some text here on this sponsored tag. Look closely and you might discover it.

[image]

Comment: These come in via our ads network, so they're a little tricky to fix behind an `iframe`. Working on it!

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The header titled **"Badge Progress"** has low contrast in the [stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats) of the review queues.

[image]

Comment: FYI this one isn't a duplicate, I checked.

Comment: Fixed as a part of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/396582#396582

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The contact us page when looking at the Enterprise solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise/get-started

[image: Contact us - when looking at Enterprise solution]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Page: [About us](https://stackoverflow.com/company)

Error: Institutional Investors cards are not shown properly with the dark mode.

[image]

Comment: I've merged a fix for this and it'll be deployed soon.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

The 3 **tooltips:** **Share**, **Edit**, **Flag** haven't been converted; **Follow** however has been converted.

[image]

Comment: FYI this one isn't a duplicate, I checked.

Comment: Aren't the 3 tooltips browser tooltips though? Maybe you could ask a new question tagged [feature-request] asking for the browser tooltips to be converted to custom tooltips for consistency.

Comment: Perhaps that's not a bad idea. But you know how SO goes, everyone's a critic so before I get massively downvoted and criticized for opening a question it's probably better to do nothing. After all, there's plenty of more knowledgeable folks on these matters and it's perhaps wiser to just sit back indifferent and let someone else take the initiative. I mean, who cares...

Comment: Or maybe browsers should make their tooltips match the user's color scheme preference or the website's color scheme. 

Comment: This has been posted as a separate question now: [Please make all of the link tooltips the same style as the “follow” tooltip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396891/10046076).

Comment: These'll get unified at some point, but I wouldn't necessarily consider this a dark mode® issue. Soon-ish!

Answer (score 2):

PNGs, SVGs, and GIFs, need to have white backgrounds, otherwise their transparency shows up dark.

Example PNG

[image: png]

Becomes

[image: transparent png on site]

Example SVG

[image: svg]

Becomes

[image]

Example GIF:

[image]

Becomes

[image]

note: I solved this on my own site with

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  img {
    background: white;
  }
}
```

Non-transparent PNG or SVG or GIF will show no issues with these settings, at least not directly since there is no background to show through and of course "jpg" has no transparency but for user images it seems like S.O. needs to default to white or else you'll get issues like those above.

Two other things I tried. One is applying an `invert(1)` filter to just PNG,GIF,SVG via `img[src$=.svg]` etc. Another is to apply `invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)` filter. But of course they only work sometimes, generally if the image is a diagram, not a photo. No good way to know AFAIK.

Note this is a separate issue from [the one about snippet results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396515/128511). That one what that snippet results need to have their iframe default to a white background. This one is about images in answers needing to have a white background.

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396071, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396105, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396192, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396736.

Comment: my bad, I just searched for "png" on each page, I should have searched for "image"

Comment: @gman this is a really cool post by itself. Because it elaborates on what other posts merely pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Requesting an offer for job postings redirects to a *Thank You!* page.

#### Thank you for getting in touch!

[image]

Comment: Good catch! Fixes for this have been pushed and will get merged and deployed after the long holiday weekend.

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Bounty award text on answers should be a lighter color, currently it doesn't have much contrast against its background. This might be less apparent with the larger screenshot attached, but in practice I thought this needed work.

[image]

Comment: This is looking how it's designed, but could probably be improved.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The **pagination label** at the **bottom** of the **"Select your next badge"** modal should be white.

[image]

Comment: This _should_ be fixed. Can you double check?

Comment: It's white on Safari, but it's still black on Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Adding a link in the tag wiki editor:
[image]

Comment: This doesn’t impact the mobile version at al, which is essentially being replaced entirely by the responsive version.

Comment: I deleted the mobile version part

Comment: This'll be deployed at some point, hopefully not too long!

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**Note:** I'm quite sure that no one has already posted this, please let me know in the comments if so and I will immediately delete my answer.</sub>

When you click on <kbd>Products</kbd>, the text in the button turns black but should instead turn white to prevent lack of contrast:

## Before click:

[image: screenshot 1]

## After click:

[image: screenshot 2]

[Fails WAIM contrast checker for normal text](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=2D2D2D&bcolor=DA670B)

Comment: The contrast is not too low, but a black (#000000) would be better.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**Note:** I'm quite sure that no one has already posted this, please let me know in the comments if so and I will immediately delete my answer.</sub>

Error message when editing is not possible is too dark:

[image: screenshot]

[Fails WAIM contrast checker for normal text](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=2D2D2D&bcolor=D25D5D)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**Note:** I'm quite sure that no one has already posted this, please let me know in the comments if so and I will immediately delete my answer.</sub>

Text in flag question button is too dark and the button's background colour should be a bit lighter to attract more attention. Also, the background colour of the box stating that a recent flag was declined is too dark:

[image: screenshot]

Button [fails all WAIM contrast tests](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=2D2D2D&bcolor=697075)

Flag declined box [fails second WAIM contrast check for normal text (AAA)](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=CFD2D6&bcolor=464236)

Answer (score 2):

Contrast in bounty score boxes on user profile is low:

[image: +50 barely readable]

It's a bit better in questions with dark text:

[image: +50 in question]

I am also not too happy with the accepted answer score boxes:

[image: white on light green text]

The WebAIM does not seem to like it either:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

The Unix & Linux icon (`favicon-unix`) lost its blue shade and is now 1 color in dark mode.

#### DARK

[image: dark-zoomed]
[image: dark-2560x1440]

#### LIGHT

[image: light-zoomed]
[image: light-2560x1440]

It becomes a bit indiscernible on high-res displays (ex. 2560x1440).

I'm not sure if related to [this other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396396/2745495), but it's already marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Short of putting a background behind the U&L logo, making it white is the only way to have it appear on the black background. The dark blues are too close to black to be visible. I'm guessing this is the "fix", so it's [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @Catija I see. While posting this, I was trying to think of a suggestion, but couldn't think of one. I guess it's not as harmful as the others, so status-by-design it is.

Answer (score 2):

So far I have not found any way to search through answers to see if a problem has been reported before. This is a terrible way to manage bug reports. Stick to bug trackers.

Anyway, these elements on the edit answer pages are not accounted for yet:

[image]

Comment: The accepted answer is a digest of all of the reported issues.

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396027 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396495.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create).

Possibly related: [Answer by Aryan Beezadhur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397389/7395911)

**First step:**

[image]

**Second step:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Although this issue was reported two times ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396190/8376184) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395999/8376184)) and marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), the additions and removals in Suggested edits queue are **still broken**:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it has not yet been deployed? Don't hurry to report it; instead wait for one day.

Comment: @double-beep I thought `status-completed` marks bugs whose fix is created **and deployed**. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 2):

#### Incorrect dark theme colors used in edit tag info pages (making the text unreadable):

On the dark theme, user notifications on the edit tag info page are unreadable in SO.

[image: Screenshot of unreadable tag user notification message]

The notification says:

```
You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
```

But is made unreadable due to the background color

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[The rise of the DevOps mindset | Stackoverflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/10/the-rise-of-the-devops-mindset/)

[image: stackoverflow blog devops]

Answer (score 2):

In review queue (in this case close questions/duplicates), text for active tabs is barely visible. I've seen multiple answers for tabs on other pages, that say "completed", but this still seems to be the case here.

[image: review queue tab text low visibility]

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26414544

Also seen in reopen queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26388629

Answer (score 2):

When you apply for a job, you get to see screen like this even when Dark Mode is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The RadioButton controls on the flagging dialog are inconsistent. On the first page they have a light background:

[image]

On subsequent pages their background is dark:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The Help Center > Badges page navigation is a bit unusually coloured

[image]

Especially on hover:

[image]

Comment: There are related issues - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396029 and scroll the top-voted answers.

Comment: This has been overhauled. Coming in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[**Top Users**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers)

[image]

Comment: This issue has already been reported.

Answer (score 1):

Hovering over a community on the communities section on a persons profile shows this white blur which was supposed to make the text look faded.

[image: Communities]

Answer (score 1):

Please, make the titles of questions white or light-gray or smth else, but not blue. Because it is hard to read. They are main texts of your site, why are they blue? For example I have time to answer some questions after work, but I can't focus on these blue titles.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Hovered items in the Products menu at the top of the main page are too bright and could do with some more contrast:

[image: bright orange]

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Maybe kind of subjective.

Highlighted sections when you click a link on the [Markdown Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists) page are unreadable:

[image: unreadable]

This may be related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395983/7518910

Comment: @double-beep was the second one already reported?

Comment: [Yes, it is reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395980)

Comment: @double-beep your link to the duplicate is wrong.

Comment: @bad_coder how? Have you looked at the revision history? Did you check the original version of the post? Wasn't the second bug already reported?

Comment: @double-beep your link is wrong because this isn't a duplicate. Simple.

Comment: @bad_coder the second one, which the OP asked, is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUCaW.png) image. How are the answer I linked and the image different?

Comment: @double-beep They might be related (I don't know), but are definitely in two separate parts of the site. The one I linked is on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists, while the answer you linked is when you click the Help button while answering a question - https://i.imgur.com/tuNHFzs.png

Comment: Disagree. Check the HTML classes. You'll realise they're the same. Check the URL. You'll realise it's the same. Also, how do you explain that also this page was fixed when Aaron added [status-completed] to my answer? They're not related, but the same.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The very link to this page has a low-contrast Meta Stack Overflow logo in it:

[image: Sidebar link “Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contract and un-converted bits” beside a low-contrast Meta Stack Overflow logo]

With more context:

[image: Page with more context]

Answer (score 1):

I strictly advise you to glance at the website using the [DarkReader](https://darkreader.org/) extension. I think it's looking exactly like what is expected.

Comment: If you want to keep using plugins for dark mode, go ahead 

Comment: @AaronShekey You've got me wrong. Actually, it signals thou - moderators - to how you should actually make the no-frills dark mode for the platform.

Comment: What browser did you try the extension on? Firefox?

Comment: @PeterMortensen chrome, sir

Answer (score 1):

Another couple things I saw on the "edit history item" part of the [story page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1434563).

First, the text in the technologies box is super hard to read while you're typing. If you look closely, you can see my little `asdf` at the end.

[image: Technologies Box]

Second, the date dropdown is black and hard to see.

[image: Date Dropdown]

Also, it's been mentioned in a couple other places in the app, but also in the timeline part the textboxes are white:

[image: White Textbox]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Tour is white

[image]
This is *especially* bad for newbies in dark mode who visit the tour. One way to solve this is to make a privilege for using dark mode (I would recommend about 200 to 500 rep), just like the **reduce ads** privilege. Another way is to make the CSS for the text black directly. I'm not sure if this is already reported or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: thank you very much and great job!

There are only 2 minor details in the settings  that I would like to report. First is in "Edit profile and settings" > "Developer Story preferences" under the "Public link" section, where the input box value is not very visible and the other input boxes (which you all can't change) are very bright.

[image: public link section screenshot]

Second is in job preferences. I know that jobs is out of scope for now, but his is in the settings and I don't know if this is the same. Either way as seen in the screenshot the "need visa sponsorship" text and the "to" are white so they aren't visible at all.

I hope this helps and nobody posted this before! First link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/7454177) and second [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/7454177).

[image: jobsearch screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Reverse colour on headlines in the Site tour site + bad background on Example screens**

As a user with a new account, I have noticed, that the [Site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) has a few bug with the newly introduced Dark-mode theme.

At first: *The Headlines of the sub-items are in wrong colour*. so you can kind of read them with the contrast, but it doesnt look really good.

Second, the *Contrast of the example screens in the site tou seems to low*, like you have changed the Text colour,but now the Background. 
you can see two examples in the picture below.

Hope it was kind of helpful.

[image: two examples of both bugs in the site tour]

Comment: Are these related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396217/10046076, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396643/10046076 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395971/10046076?

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Filtering questions 
e.g. [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)

The title "Sponsored links for this tag" and the bullets list are too dark.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396616.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The [**Vote Synonyms**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/control-flow/synonyms) arrows appear to have some imperfections that weren't perceptible in light-mode.

[image]

Comment: FYI this one isn't a duplicate, I checked. OP mentioned "site sprites" specifically, I'm unsure if these should be posted.

Comment: Hmm... I think this is more of an issue with SO using outdated sprites. You could possibly open a new question asking for the sprites to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I saw on the bug list on page 1 "contact", but I'm not sure we're talking about the same page so I'm posting it with an image.

https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Note:** I'm quite sure that no one has already posted this, please let me know in the comments if so and I will immediately delete my answer.</sub>

Please increase the contrast on the elements alongside the question (upvote/downvote buttons, vote total, bookmark button and timeline button).

They don't stand out from the rest of the page as much as in light mode.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Note:** I'm quite sure that no one has already posted this, please let me know in the comments if so and I will immediately delete my answer.</sub>

Developer story form input fields are still white instead of dark grey like the search bar with my user tag:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396642 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396656. Should probably keep answer until further confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Note:** I'm quite sure that no one has already posted this, please let me know in the comments if so and I will immediately delete my answer.</sub>

The text in the selected navigation tab on my profile page should be white, not black:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[Fails WAIM contrast checker for normal text](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=2D2D2D&bcolor=DA670B)

Comment: If it was white, it would lack sufficient contrast (2.63:1). Black does have sufficient contrast (7.95:1).

Answer (score 1):

The filter on the [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) is not in Dark Mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/########/xxxxxxxxxxx`

When clicking on a badge (the "next badge" and "next privilege" also act in the same way):

[image]
[image]

Comment: already reported here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395950/578411

Comment: My bad ... I scrolled through the answers too fast.
I'm leaving this answer here in any case since I also mentioned "next badge" and "next priviliege".

Comment: Yeah, I knew I saw it earlier but couldn't find it easily either.

Answer (score 0):

Images in questions are affected by dark mode,
Question link: [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Real Image:
[image: Image showing all the arrows correctly]

Image after dark mode:

[image: Image shown in dark mode]

Comment: Already reported - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396071.

Comment: This is a good example of the issue though so I added a note about it in my answer with a reference to you in case this is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, even if you put on Dark Mode, the calendar (the one that shows your consecutive days) is still bright. It doesn't fit in with the rest of the profile on Dark Mode.

See:
[image]
The consecutive days calendar in the middle right is white, but I want it to be a bit darker to blend in with the other ones. Also, the color of the text should stay white and the green consecutive days should stay green. Just the background should be a little bit darker.

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: This is the only mention of the calendar, afaik. It's a legitimate feature-request if not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The **overlay-header** div hasn't been converted yet.

[image: overlay-header screenshot]

Here's the tag for the div:

```
<div id="overlay-header" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">Welcome back! If you found this question useful,<br>don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.<br><a class="close-overlay">close this message</a></div>
```

Comment: Already reported: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396163/10046076.

Answer (score 0):

In the profile section where you may select which badge to track, the text sort of blends in and is hard to read.

[image: the issue]

Comment: Did you check out the rest of the answers to see if this has already been reported?

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The current color weights for the announcements/pinned posts header look a little... bleurgh...

It's not perfect (contrast is still an issue with the chosen favicons, and a small problem with the white on gold background), but I've found these color changes to be a good start on fixing that:

```css
.s-sidebarwidget__yellow .s-sidebarwidget--header {
    background-color: #9e883b;
}

.s-sidebarwidget__yellow {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

Example:

[image: New]

Comment: This looks like something out of Star Trek TNG. 

Comment: @Catija It *does* give off Geordi LaForge vibes, now that you mention it.

Comment: If we're going to touch this component, I'd like to just change it to grayscale, which already exists as a variant. https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/sidebar-widgets/

Comment: @AaronShekey To be clear, are you declining the request to adjust the current colors? Or did you intend to decline the suggested colors? The colors I suggested in the answer were just an example. Your comment about grayscale already existing is a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm declining the colors as they're proposed. If anything, we'd remove the class `.s-sidebarwidget__yellow` to go with the default grayscale colors from that component.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This box about Flair, see freehand circle, could use some love.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found another one: the text for the decline reason is hard to see against the dark background.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395972/10046076?

Comment: @Zera yes it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In **User Profile Activity** the meta-SO icon is very low contrast.

[image]

Comment: FYI this specific one isn't a duplicate, I checked. Although similar icons occurring in other parts of the site have been reported.

Comment: *Site sprites (appear in the site switcher or on profile pages) haven't been adapted to the dark theming. This means sites icons with dark colors (e.g. Super User, U&L, Salesforce, Wordpress, etc) may be difficult to see.* - from the question.

Comment: @double-beep The question **didn't** say we shouldn't post this. Users perusing are bound to enjoy an illustrated inventory.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396048 (so, don't hurry to mention you checked all the answers).

Comment: @double-beep **obviously isn't a duplicate**. The icons are placed in completely different sections. Take notice of detail before erroneously claiming a post is duplicate, I've seen other instances where you claimed duplicates that weren't true with broken links to go with it.

Comment: So, what if they are placed in different section? Aren't they the exact same icons (only the background differs)? They even have the same classes: [site switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV12A.png), [user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdw0K.png). Not sure why you mention a bug SE staff already knows!

Answer (score 0):

This bug is similar as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396056 but I found it at "Watched Tags" section.
The dropdown selection at edit "Watched Tags" with white background.

[image: Watched Tags]

And the textbox background still white color while loading tag.

[image: search tag]

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: Overlay header]
Overlay header

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396163, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396399, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396607 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396350.

Answer (score 0):

Triage review queue:
The review tab has unreadable black text and turns white when hovered over.

[image]
[image]

Found at: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26143865

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395984, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395960, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396029, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395966, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396227, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396186, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396190 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396062.

Comment: @Zera not sure how those are duplicates? Those refer to different parts of the site than the one I pointed out.

Comment: (Most of them) refer to the exact same component, and components are reused across the site.

Comment: @Zera that's not clear unless we know & see the implementation. I think the report should stand as is since it's not clear that's the case since it only happens to specific tabs (e.g. "review") but doesn't happen to others (e.g. "history"). Moreover, all those were allowed to stand even though they also refer to similar components.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The contrast of the box in the sidebar on the election page is low:

[image: Low contrast on election page]

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/election/11

Comment: Not quite sure what warrants a downvote here... is this a duplicate?

Comment: Seems to be fixed now, I'll mark completed.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answers have a weird, bright yellow selected like background around them. This doesn't happen on every accepted answer, and so far I've only had it happen to answers accepted a long time ago.

The only way I can seem to make it go away is by selecting the text (which doesn't highlight as selected because of it) and then click outside the text a couple of times. Refreshing the page makes the text background yellow again.

[image]
Answer from the screenshot is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4642146/8628766

Using Google Chrome 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 (64-bit)

Comment: Can't reproduce this with Firefox. Could it be related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398033)?

Comment: Yes that does seem to be it @BillTür . Looking at Martijn's answer and my url it does contain the `:~:text` he mentions. I should've looked for global bug (feature?) reports rather than just in here. Thanks for bringing up that post.

Answer (score -1):

The mobile site doesn't seem to have a dark theme at all. This is no big deal (well, it's be nice but I'm not expecting the mobile site to get much love until the main site is fully ironed out), except that switching to dark theme on a desktop now seems to mean that some parts of the mobile site, that were mobile presented, have acquired the desktop dark theme page - for example the tags list used to be a nice compact listing of all the tags and no extra descriptive blurb. Now on a mobile it seems to be the desktop version of he tag list, replete with verbiage and it has lost the nav at the top:

[image]

Of the following nav bar items:

[image]

Questions, jobs and badges remain white mobile, and tags, users and ask drop to desktop version dark pages. I'd like the mobile site to be consistently mobile at least

Answer (score -1):

The **bounty sum** still has white text:

[image]

It also appears in the list of questions as white:

[image]

And the blue around it looks suspiciously light to me, too.

White text sticks out like a sore thumb in the ultra-dark mode, for ease of detection, even if that style is not going to be persisted in public.

Comment: If it was darker, then you couldn't see it.

Comment: @zixuan That would be compensated for by reducing the brightness of the blue.

Answer (score -1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

**Images in " Help Center > Privileges " are not set as dark mode images:**

For example:

Help Center > Privileges > Set bounties:

[image]

Help Center > Privileges > Flag posts:

[image]

and we can see the same images without dark mode in:

Help Center > Privileges > Established user

Help Center > Privileges > Reduce ads

Help Center > Privileges > Access to site analytics

Help Center > Privileges > Access to moderator tools

Help Center > Privileges > Create tag synonyms

Comment: We don't really have a way to change these images based on background color. These pages are created pretty much with the same editor as posts are made with, so there's no way to serve a different image based on the mode you're using.

Comment: but it's not good at dark mode

Comment: Images aren’t something any site can really solve for... so, say we make this part of the site in dark mode... your answer here will have the identical problem. We just can’t fix that. An image is an image.

Comment: ok I just suggested that

Comment: Also, @Alirezaaraby, you don't need to have both light and dark mode. This is just to show new privilege earners what it looks like. Light and dark mode have the same text. The only difference is the colors.

Answer (score -2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I type a comment:

[image]

Really hard to see what to type in...

Comment: This has already been reported!

Comment: @double-beep If you're going to leave comments like that on answers, please **include a link** to the answer where you think it's already been reported. Otherwise, the comment is useless.

Comment: Already covered in [double-beep's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/395980#395980).

Comment: @CodyGray isn't that something that should be done by the OP?

Comment: @double-beep I don't see how that would be the OP's job. If they'd seen the other answer you had in mind, then they wouldn't have posted a duplicate. On the contrary, if you're going to make the claim that the answer is a duplicate of an existing answer, then you should provide some evidence. Think of it this way: if I have proof that the answer is a duplicate, it makes it easier for me to prune.

Comment: @double-beep Yes, the OP should be searching for duplicates. But if you're going to comment about it being a dupe, just like with a question, point to the dupe. OPs are supposed to search for those too...

Answer (score -2):

Entire page is still light mode

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary

Answer (score -2):

[image: Selected tabs are not visible]

Comment: An explanation would be in order (by [editing your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/396612/edit), not here in comments). Also, some [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I report similar bug

Answer (score -2):

In dark-mode [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), the active tab has hard-to-read font color (e.g. selected tab "milestone" at the bottom of screenshot). To this moment nobody report this bug on this page. Maybe similar problem occures in other pages, bud I don't know that that pages are independent or they use some shared code - so I report it

[image]

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396029, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395966, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396186, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396190 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396062.

Answer (score -3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When a new question arrived in your watch list tag

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure if should be reported here or if it has been spotted already but a cursory search didn't find anything on Meta so I'll post it.

As you see in the screenshot below, in dark mode, when you select an option, the text is the same as the background and becomes invisible.

I'm on Chrome and Ubuntu Linux.

[image]

Answer (score -6):

(EDIT - removed the suggested outline approach as nobody liked that either)

The background of this section looks bad (it's garish even in normal/light mode IMO), makes the SO icon of the bottom three sections look too faded out, and hurts readability.

[image: Yellow background]

Comment: Sorry, but I hate the outline.

Comment: @DavidG no problem, you weren't alone so I removed it. It's easier to throw stones than to fix glass. I still think the yellow should be adjusted.

Comment: I think they should fix the icon rather than the background colour.

Comment: I think the murky brown/orangy background colour of this block is awesome!

Comment: I think the murky brown/orangy background is a horrible color. While I don't think the now-removed suggestion was perfect, I think it was acceptable and *far* better than what's currently implemented.

Answer (score -10):

The scrollbar is not dark enough. Try out this CSS for Webkit-based browsers:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar /* the scrollbar itself */
{
    width: 10px;
    background: #393939;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track /* the scrollbar track (the scrollbar's working area) */
{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb /* the part of the scrollbar that you move */
{
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover /* the part of the scrollbar that you move, on hover */
{
    background: #222;
}
```

which can turn this scrollbar:

[image: The original, standard scrollbar for Chrome, included with Windows]

into one like this:

[image: The new scrollbar, powered by Devdrive]

Comment: Web pages should not attempt to change system-level widgets. There's a reason this kind of trickery is WebKit-specific. If you want dark scroll bars, configure your OS accordingly.

Comment: But most OS'es have no configuration for _that_ scrollbar.

Comment: And, you have no configuration options for _specific_ scrollbars.

Comment: Devdrive does this on WebKit-based browsers and it works.

Comment: CSS Tricks has a cool scrollbar change.

Comment: Firefox automatically changes the scrollbar color based on the page's background color and it looks nice.

Comment: We'll be leaving the browser-wide scrollbar alone. ✌️

Comment: But SO needs to have this functionality done for WebKit, which doesn't do the auto-change like Gecko does.

Comment: @CodyGray: There really isn't a good reason for this. The most likely one being that exposing this was overlooked in the initial HTML/CSS specs. This is going to be rectified in the future with the [CSS scrollbars module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/).  Based on your reasoning one should not change the color of input fields either; there is no real basis for this distinction.

Answer (score -40):

It's absolutely wonderful!

Who cares about the odd bug?

(Yes the advertisements stick out a bit unless you fiddle with your browser.)

Comment: Well, don't know about the others, but I care about the odd bug. I've seen many software products offer dark mode and unfortunately *most* have huge issues that prevent me using it. It's always some key functionality that's also not immediately obvious, so I might use this for a week or a month and suddenly find something that's absolutely unusable with this theme. There was one where you couldn't *edit the settings* because you couldn't see them. An editor made config files unreadable, another did the same for *comments* but you could see code. So, I care about bugs.

Comment: When text is literally unreadable, I care about that. And when it's technically readable but hurts my eyes to look at it, then that defeats the entire purpose of dark mode.

Comment: I agree it may not be a big deal, but for some people who stare at their computers for too long(aka me), the eyes need pleasing images. Yes, I care about bugs.