# How do I enable/disable the Light/Dark Theme on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page, dark-mode, faq-proposed

I've heard that [Stack Overflow now has a Dark Theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949)! However, I can't find the way to enable it.

Or, equivalently: I managed to enable the Dark Theme on Stack Overflow, but now I can't find how to deactivate it in order to return to the original light mode.

I didn't see anything on the home page, in the top bar, or on my profile page. How can I do this?

Comment: God forbid it occurs to StackOverflow to use 24 pixels of screen real estate to add it to the main nav bar.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can change the site mode from the Preferences page for your user account on Stack Overflow.

Here is a direct link to the *Preferences* page for your logged-in account:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

Otherwise, to navigate to this page yourself, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you are on the main Stack Overflow site (not Meta—there is no Dark Theme support on Meta).
2. Click on your avatar in the top bar.
3. Click on "Settings"

Once you are on the appropriate page, select the option corresponding to the theme that you prefer.

- The "Dark" option will enable the Dark Theme, forcing it to always be on.
- The "Light" option will remove/disable the Dark Theme, forcing the original light mode to always be used.
- The "System setting" option will automatically choose the mode, based on your system configuration.

[image: Screenshot of the preferences page, showing the three options, light, dark, and system setting.]
(click the image to see an animated GIF of how to get there)

Comment: Note that this setting *does not* seem to apply to Meta Stack Overflow, e.g., even when you have dark enabled on Stack Overflow, Meta will still be light.  I checked for a separate theme setting on Meta, but for whatever reason it is missing.

Comment: @TaylorD.Edmiston That's correct: *"there is no Dark Theme support on Meta"*

Comment: So, *why* is there no dark theme support on Meta?