# Using dark theme but 'Job near you is not applied'

Tags: bug, bug-reporting-process

As the picture I captured from mine.

[image: Stackoverflow dark theme but it's not with Job near you section]

Comment: Thanks for the report! This was mentioned on our [mass thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395955/4548692) already so I'm closing this as a dupe. :D