# Is the dark theme really here to last or is it just an April fools day joke?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, dark-mode

Is the dark theme/mode really here to last or is it just an April fools day joke?

I, of course, hope it's here to stay, however, it seems to be missing in some places e.g. meta.

Comment: It's a lot (and I do mean *lot*) of work for an April Fool's gag.

Comment: The announcement said that it wasn't available in Meta initially. Once the bugs have been cleared then it'll be deployed to other sites - though some of the other network sites with complex themes will probably never get it. I can see Super User and Server Fault getting it.

Comment: I guess this year's April Fools joke was fooling us into thinking that the dark theme is this year's April Fools joke.

Answer (score 19):

Official word from staff is that the "dark theme" option is here to stay—it is *not* a temporary April Fools' joke.

Answer (score 15):

It is here to last, *but* the new Ultra Dark mode is this year's April Fools' joke:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [related meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949#comment763338_395950)

Answer (score -6):

I would reckon it's here to stay. It's absolutely beautiful and shows really mature display. Nice work, and as has been pointed out, the theme does not show up in a meta-pages, and this page in particular