# Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links in dark mode

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, dark-mode

I'm not a UX expert, but in my experience, visited links are usually styled with a "more dull" color. With this new dark mode, it seems to be quite the opposite.

In the CSS,

- `--theme-link-color` is `var(--blue-600)` (`#33a7ff`)
- `--theme-link-color-visited` is `var(--blue-700)` (`#81c5f8`)

Here are some examples:

**Home Page:**

[image: Home Page]

**Sidebar:**

[image: Sidebar]

**Profile Activity** (Votes, Responses, All actions):<sup>*</sup>

[image: Profile Activity tabs]

In all the examples above, it's always the "brighter color" that is used to indicate visited links and the "more dull" color is used to indicate non-visited links. That seems counterintuitive to me and I'm mistaking them all the time. I think it's more obvious in the second and third examples. I used to immediately spot newly featured Meta posts that I haven't visited. Well, not anymore.

---

<sub>(Feel free to skip this part)</sub>

<sub>For comparison, this is how it looked like with a Chrome extension that I used before the SO Dark Mode was released:</sub>

[image: Home Page using a Chrome extension]

<sub>..and this is how Reddit, for example, handles visited links in dark mode:</sub>

[image: Reddit]

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>There's also the inconsistency issue with this one. It uses this styling only for the last 3 tabs (under Profile > Activity). The remaining tabs use the same styling that's used for the Home Page.</sub>

Comment: Even in light mode it’s really difficult to tell visited links apart from non-visited ones, and to interpret which is which, especially on MSE.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the announcement post has been locked for a long time and [we've been encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408514/why-does-stack-overflow-use-a-monochromatic-logo-in-dark-mode#comment849922_408514) to post related FRs and bug reports as separate questions.

Comment: Using light mode, I just realized reading this question and the first comment that there are different colors for visited and non-visited. It's very subtle to say the least

Comment: @Sleepwalker Haven't used light mode in a very long time but if I remember correctly, there used to be a distinction between visited and non-visited links. It still exists [here, on meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yekR8.png) (though, not so obvious). Edit: apparently, it's still there on the main site too (light mode) but it's very difficult to notice (making it useless). Maybe this is caused by the recent change to fonts.

Comment: Workaround: [Override the unvisited and visited link colours locally](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257) (at least Firefox and Chrome). I use `a:visited { color:OrangeRed!important; }`  (and don't override the unvisited one) - it works fine for both dark mode and other sites than Stack Overflow. (Yes, it is the opposite effect, but you get the point.)