# Dark mode contrast: regular text has much higher contrast than `--theme-post-title-color`

Tags: discussion, dark-mode

At the time of this writing, in dark mode, the regular text has much higher contrast against the site background than `--theme-post-title-color` does.

The current values are:

- `color: #E7E9EB`
- `--theme-content-background-color` -> `var(--white): #2d2d2d`
- `--theme-post-title-color` -> `var(--theme-link-color)` -> `--blue-600: #33a7ff`

Links to [WebAIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAIM):

- [For regular text contrast](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=E7E9EB&bcolor=2D2D2D)

  - contrast ratio: 11.31:1
- [For `--theme-post-title-color` contrast](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=33A7FF&bcolor=2D2D2D)

  - contrast ratio: 5.32:1

I found that when going through the review queues, people tend to put the main/basic question in the title, and not duplicate the basic question in the question body, but rather only put elaboration there. I have no problem with this.

What I find nonideal is that my eyes get easily drawn immediately to the question body over the question title, because the body's contrast is so much higher, which is a little frustrating—or at least counterintuitive, since I will usually only understand the question body by first reading the title.

Yes, this is easily solved by "just exert that iota of effort to read the title first", but I think it would be much better if the contrast ratios were more similar, so that I wouldn't have to fight against what my brain naturally does.

Perhaps that means brightening `--theme-post-title-color`. Perhaps that means darkening the default `color`. `--theme-post-title-color` is probably the less controversial choice, since the default color is the default color for the whole site.

Interestingly, `--theme-post-title-color-visited` uses `--theme-link-color-visited`, which is `--blue-700`. I found this to be satisfactory in being more similar in contrast-ratio with the regular text color. Edit: I just found that [a discussion already exists about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396792/11107541)

Aside: I also thought it was curious since generally in light mode, it seems like the de facto style is to make visited links darker so that they stand out *less*. So it seems strange that in dark mode, stackoverflow.com makes them stand out *more*—not that I have any actual reason to think that's a bad thing—it just stood out as not very normal, but this is besides the point of this thread.