# Misleading link color: unvisited questions look visited

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Question links of (additionally) watched questions are light blue, as if I had visited them. Example from [Questions tagged [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

[image: python tag search results]

I didn't visit "does pip..." but did visit "API request...". The former is light blue apparently because I'm additionally watching the `python-3.x` tag.

On the [start page](https://stackoverflow.com/) it's even worse, now all `python` question links are light blue as if I had visited them.

I think this started today because it's very confusing/irritating, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If it did start today, it's likely related to [Watched question titles are changed to blue on themed sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381863/165261) - seems it's not just themed sites this happened on.

Comment: As an aside, all visited links, at least in the light theme, are so similar to the link color that it's completely useless

Comment: This definitely started yesterday or today.

Comment: Yep, it started yesterday. Also, reported here: [Please test design / colour changes in dark mode and site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381873/348196)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396792/8967612)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue was caused by a non-theme color being set on watched post summary titles in a recent design system change. We've reverted that change and shipped the reversion. Thanks for the report!