# Please fix the contrast between visited and unvisited links

Tags: bug, status-review, design, hyperlinks

The contrast difference when a link is visited is *completely* unusable. Here's two questions side-by-side, where one is visited and the other isn't:

> [image: screenshot showing two nearly identically colored links, where one is visited and the other isn't]

For comparison, here's Ecosia:

> [image: screenshot of Ecosia showing a visited link in a purple-ish color, while unvisited links are a standard blue]

And here's two different random questions with the same setup as the first screenshot, where the visited link uses Ecosia's style:

> [image: Screenshot of two random questions, still one visited and one unvisited, with the visited link now clearly differentiable from the unvisited link]

(This isn't a color recommendation. It's just a demonstration of how any sufficiently different color makes visited links usable again)

The problem here is that the visited links are #0a95ff, while unvisited are #379fef. These two colors are incredibly similar:

> [image: screenshot showing one of the colors as text on a background of the other]

Which is a problem when `:visited` links are meant to be different from unvisited links. In their current state, they're impossible to tell apart.

---

As an aside, if anyone else is equally annoyed and want a fix now, here's the userstyle rule I use:

```css
body.unified-theme {
    --theme-post-title-color-visited: <color>;
    --theme-link-color-visited: var(--theme-post-title-color-visited);
}
```

There are some links not caught by this, presumably because I'm missing a few variables, and override rules are weird, but it covers the vast majority of use-cases

Comment: Yes! This is even worse than the contrast between un/visited links on MSE, and [it's not good there either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376114).

Comment: In case anybody wonders how it looks in high contrast dark mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7JuV.png The visited link is the third from the top: "Multiplying a singular..."

Comment: Related: [Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396792)

Comment: Wasn't there a recent (within one or two weeks) meta question about this?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No. You're probably thinking about [Misleading link color: unvisited questions look visited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420272/6296561), which was a bug with watched tags making some unvisited links look visited. I made this complaint in the comments back then, but the question itself wasn't about that, nor was that bit addressed

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine: Yes, wrong site. I was thinking of the 2022-09-15 *[Recent Color Contrast Changes and Accessibility Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382079/)* (on Über Meta)—e.g., *"We started rolling out some color contrast changes"*. It has a broader scope, and it references a question from April 2020 here, *[Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396792/)*.

Comment: This has bothered me for a long time, but somehow it never occurred to me to post about it.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: A workaround is to [override it in the browser](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257). I use "`a:visited { color:OrangeRed!important; }`" for visited and don't override the unvisited.