# Diff in dark mode is near unreadable

Tags: bug

I'm using dark mode for Stack Overflow, and as I was reviewing suggested edits.

I found an issue with it:

[image: Issue]

Basically, the diff can't be read. On Chrome 81.0.4044.129 / macOS Catalina 10.15.4

It happens only on the **Markdown renderer**.

Comment: It's reported here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395999/2745495.

Comment: My bad, I'm not used to Meta.