# Dark theme with black label on privileges tabs

Tags: discussion, support, design

I've encountered a small design issue with the dark theme;

When you go to the privileges page in the [help/wiki site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=milestone), then the selected tab's font color is black in the dark theme. This looks like this, thus it's a bit hard to read:
[image]

Comment: Like the third screen shot from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/395960#395960)?

Comment: yeah, sorry, didn't see it in the results

Comment: No worries. It's kind of unusual that we are consolidating all bugs related to this feature in the same post. Normally, we do recommend that a separate question be opened for all bugs. Just want to clarify that having your question closed as a duplicate is not a slap on the wrist or a sign that you did anything wrong, especially on Meta.