# Company filter affordance is misleading

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, design, companies-page

At Stack Overflow jobs' [companies page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) we have the option to filter some of the companies based on some options. Three of those are check-boxes, and they work just fine.

The problem I'm reporting is due to some misleading representation of the filters as buttons. We can click on them, however they only work when clicking precisely on the check-box or its text, and if you just click on the button elsewhere you just interact without any response.

What I suggest is to allow the button click to trigger the filter or to change its design. However my point here is mainly to point out this weird behavior.

On the following image I present those filters, I'm using Dark Mode, but their behavior is the same even without it so this post shouldn't be placed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/7395911).

[image]