# Strange highlighting for a few seconds

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, google-chrome, google, seo

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255696/way-to-disable-the-visual-studio-code-editor-title-bar#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=You%20can%20use%20this%20setting,and%20set%20it%20to%20custom.) Stack Overflow topic, I've seen this strange behaviour:

[image]

It happened right when I started my browser, and it was the first page I loaded. Additionally, the page becomes unresponsive for about 5 seconds (cannot click anything, no hovering reaction). After that, the page wakes up and after you click anywhere else the highlighting disappears.

The behavior is the same after I reload the exact same page. It doesn't happen for me on any other page.

Restarting the browser helped though.

Comment: And they say that I have a lot of Tabs open.

Comment: @BotMaster3000 it's only one of 3 open browsers though

Comment: Cross-site post on MSE: [Yellow highlighted text in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349128/289905).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The highlight is a [Google search feature](https://www.google.com/amp/s/9to5google.com/2020/06/03/google-search-highlight-website-content/amp/), where it’ll show the matching section on the page by adding a specially formatted URL hash fragment ([starting with `:~:text=`](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#tldr)). You got to that page by clicking on a  *featured snippet* at the top of a Google search result and are using Chrome. Google [rolled out the feature worldwide this week](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/4/21280115/google-search-engine-yellow-highlight-featured-snippet-anchor-text) after testing it in limited settings for a while.

This is not a Stack Overflow feature, and the feature is not limited to just Stack Overflow search results. This is Google’s search engine hooking into Google’s browser (and any other browser that supports [Google's proposed scroll-to-text fragment specification](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096)).

See [these instructions on how to turn it off](https://perishablepress.com/disable-chrome-scrolltotextfragment/).

Stack Overflow *could* choose to disable the feature, either by adding a [`Document-Policy: force-load-at-top` HTTP header](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#opting-out) (which disables **all** fragment scrolling, including linking to answers and comments), or by [disabling featured snippet support entirely](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325). Both options look to me to have too broad an effect, and don't think they would be good options.

Comment: Would it be in the interest of SO users for SO to conditionally disable the feature on content pertaining to answers with score <0?