# Why is some text highlighted in some answers?

Tags: discussion

Am I seeing this as part of a new A/B test on the site? Or is this a new feature that everyone sees? Also what are its behaviours? (i.e. is AI causing the highlight, and what is that based on e.g. my google search query, something else).

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339852)

[image]

Note, the url so that anyone can view the same highlight is:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339697/what-does-this-mean-zshrc#:~:text=script%20that%20is,order%20to%20exploit%20this%20script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339697/what-does-this-mean-zshrc#:%7E:text=script%20that%20is,order%20to%20exploit%20this%20script).

Comment: Note: some differences with the duplicate question: no time out before highlight changes (it stays highlighted), I experience none of the reported unresponsiveness, inability to click, inability to hover. But the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398034/5783745) answers most of this question

Comment: The link also doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @Zoe that is expected behaviour as this seems to be one that is visible only for users who 1. arrived via a google search and 2. Are using google chrome browser. (that’s if correctly interpreted the related question’s answer correctly)

Comment: _“[S]ome differences with the duplicate question: no time out before highlight changes (it stays highlighted)”_ — the culprit of this issue is still the same, and it doesn’t matter how Google Chrome decides to behave exactly; it’s not Stack Exchange’s feature or bug, so I don’t see why this should be reopened.

Comment: @user4642212 I think this development is a big deal, for the following reasons: i) makes SO behave/appear significantly different to users depending on how they arrived and their browser, ii) it's not (at first glance) intuitive that the highlighting is being done by google (I first frolicked about in the answer's source code for some highlighting tag), (perhaps most importantly) iii) by highlighting potentially incorrect answers, it circumvents the SO system's own judgements on what content is more or less right or wrong. Maybe this is all only surprising on the first occasion.

Comment: @stevec Okay, yes, this sounds like a SEO issue for Stack Exchange, but then it should still be discussed on the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398033/4642212).

Comment: @user4642212 I left a comment there (only regarding the third point), hopefully that starts some discussion. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398033/strange-highlighting-for-a-few-seconds#comment773966_398034