# Election tabs are black-on-black: the dark theme styling needs to be fixed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-election, dark-mode

The active tab in elections has black text on a dark gray background. The other tabs also have low contrast:

[image]

In addition, when hovering over an active tab on an election page, the tab background becomes white:

[image]

Hovering over the inactive tabs triggers even lower contrast than before:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been switched to a dark mode-aware component. Going out in the next production build.