# Post highlighting in the review queues is not usable under dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, design, dark-mode

This was [first reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395983/8967612) on March 30th. Here's a gif demonstration of the issue:

[image: Demo]

This happens only with answers and it happens in three review queues:

- First Posts (answers only).
- Low Quality Posts (answers only).
- Late Answers (all posts, obviously).

Reviewing in these three queues while using dark mode is almost impossible without getting sore eyes. It's been four and a half months already. **Are there any plans to fix this bug?**

**December 2020 Update:**

I'm coming from the future to tell you that this hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: You have waited 6 to 8 years to get dark mode. It takes at least 6 to 8 months to fix the known the bugs

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up again! As your list points out... my first question is why we have this at all in review... it seems like we're using the answer anchor action, which highlights the post to help you see it when the page jumps to the answer... in review, which is unnecessary since the answer is right there, front and center. Aaron's already fixed the jump to post highlighting in dark mode so the effect should be easy to change... but I think the "correct" solution here may be to drop the highlighting for both light and dark - any big concerns here? Does the highlighting help y'all?

Comment: I guess that the highlighting may help you notice that it *is* an answer - is that the big benefit? Are there others?

Comment: @Catija I agree with you. I think the highlighting is not needed in review but I can't speak for everyone.

Comment: @Catija I think the highlighting may be a useful visual cue that the page has updated. I would just make the simple fix for now, rather than trying to drop highlighting altogether.

Comment: @CodyGray But it's currently only used with answers and only in those 3 queues, so no consistency.

Comment: @Catija I agree it's unneeded - I had at no point, noticed that it meant that - especially since I have the LQP queue filtered to answers only.

Comment: This is still an issue. My eyes burn.

Comment: Still an issue... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401823/weird-animated-transition-in-queue-on-dark-mode

Comment: @rene 6 to 8 months have passed and this didn't even get a [status-review] :'(

Comment: @41686d6564 you missed I said *at least* ... ;)

Comment: @rene I'll report back in 6 to 8 decades then. Hopefully, dark mode will still be a thing.

Comment: Still an issue! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402639/disable-the-fade-out-effect-when-loading-a-post-in-late-answers. Just how long will my eyes burn out? In dark mode when loading a link to an answer, it has the same affect. Also note that you have the thank button :)

Comment: @Catija No need to highlight at all. There is a big, bold title above the post body that tells you it is an answer; if that causes confusion for people who aren't paying close enough attention, then, well... that's what review suspensions are for :-)

Comment: If it helps narrow things down on your end, this looks like a manual change of the `<div class="mainbar reviewable-answer">` through a `style` attribute that updates the background color. This animation looks like it's done through `review.js`. Fixing it would require changing the `newAnswerStartingColor` and `defaultAnswerColor` to dark mode colors (or removing the animation altogether). Changing `defaultAnswerColor = '#2D2D2D'` instead of `#FFF` does a pretty good job of fixing this.

Comment: Digging even further, this is just modifying the call to `StackExchange.review.init` in an inline `script` tag on the page. Right now it has `{"newAnswerStartingColor":"#F4A83D","defaultAnswerColor":"#FFF",...});`, but should probably read the CSS theme variables instead.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Pollard this helped narrow it down!

Comment: @Kyle Did you just... `@` (and thank) yourself? :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a sight for sore eyes!

[image: A demonstration of the highlight animation that fades from yellow to black instead of yellow to white.]

I had an older revision of this answer where I made a user script to fix this, but since then I've been hired at Stack Overflow and can fix this myself!

This was using a hardcoded color which faded to white, even on dark mode. With my fix, this fades to a transparent color and will work on any background on any site. The text is now readable throughout the entire highlighting animation and you're no longer blinded by the flash of white!

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Kyle, and congrats on the job :)