# Disable the fade-out effect when loading a post in Late Answers

Tags: support, review-queues, late-answers

I was doing some reviewing work in Late Answers, when I realized that the post fading out when it loaded was significantly slowing down my reviewing.

Is there any way to disable this?

I noticed this doesn't happen in Triage or First Posts.

Here is a GIF of the behavior:

[image]

This is the issue only for answers, not questions.

Related: [Post highlighting in the review queues is not usable under dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399427/post-highlighting-in-the-review-queues-is-not-usable-under-dark-mode)

Comment: Flash? Do you mean the 'fade out' effect normally used for new posts?

Comment: @Tom I think so

Comment: I misunderstood the title at first and wondered why they were still using Flash in 2020.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It *is* a bit misleading. I'll edit my post to improve terminology.

Comment: This only occurs in dark mode, so for the people whose eyes don't burn out with light mode, you will need to switch. @GalaxyCat105 You may want to include a screenshot or gif of the behavior. I have insterted one for you.

Comment: @10Rep I've inserted a GIF now.

Comment: I don't use Dark Mode on Stack Overflow (as my colour vision and SO's dark colour scheme don't work together), but in light mode, the effect is exactly the same in First Posts as it is in Late Answers so you might want to double-check that. I agree Triage does not have this effect. I have to say it's far less annoying in light mode than it appears to be in dark mode, judging by your gif.

Comment: @DavidBuck For some reason, I'm not able to reproduce it using light mode in First Posts.

Comment: Highly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399427/post-highlighting-in-the-review-queues-is-not-usable-under-dark-mode

Comment: Ah. It's only answers, not questions. That explains Triage and, I assume, our differing experiences of First Posts.

Comment: @DavidBuck Yes, but why only for answers?

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 According to staff, it's actually a bug. See [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399427/post-highlighting-in-the-review-queues-is-not-usable-under-dark-mode#comment782701_399427)