# Selecting filter options for review is barely readable in dark mode

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, dark-mode

I went to the reviews today and wanted to change filter, but it was barely readable. This is what it looked like:

[image]

Don't know if it has something to do with Firefox. My version is 68.10.0esr (64-bit)

Comment: Previously reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397393).