# Dark theme changes unexpectedly on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, dark-mode

When we are on the "Activity" tab and we switch to the "Developer Story" tab,
URLs:

- ["Activity" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/smthing/smthing-smthing?tab=topactivity) → had Dark theme enabled:
  [image]
- ["Developer Story"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/smthing) tab → clicked → No Dark Theme here:
  [image]

After going on the "Developer Story" tab, Dark theme is gone. It changes unexpectedly. I just changed from activity to story. *Bad user experience!*

I was working at night and suddenly, white light came up on eyes.

Comment: [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949)

Comment: That question is locked ...

Comment: yes, but it's mentioned in the second paragraph: "There are some outstanding issues, particularly related to the Developer Story page, which is difficult to fix without breaking a lot of things". Read: They're aware, and they're struggling to fix it

Comment: @Zoe yeah, True