# The dark theme changes unexpectedly on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

When we are on the `Activity` tag and we switch to the `Developer Story` tag,

URLs:
`Activity` tag -> had Dark theme enabled
https://stackoverflow.com/users/smthing/smthing-smthing?tab=topactivity
`Developer Story` tag -> clicked -> No Dark Theme here
https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/smthing

[image: pe]

On the`Developer Story` tag:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashish,
what is your question?

Comment: @Nash cant you see, Dark theme changes unexpectedly, i just changed Activity to Story, BAD USER EXPERIENCE, i was working at Night suddenly White light came up on eyes

Comment: Looks like you cross-posted this question to different sites. Here’s your original report on Meta: [Dark theme changes unexpectedly on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399642/dark-theme-changes-unexpectedly-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @user4642212 yes, thanks its migrated and answered