# Issue on Company background color

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design, dark-mode

When you reach [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/11528/facebook?storyType=1) you will see a not uniform background colour when you have dark-mode ON:

[image: company users]

- From a user developer story [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/100297)
- Click on a company popup to see the employees list

[image: how to reach]

Related to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399642/dark-theme-changes-unexpectedly-on-stack-overflow) that asks for the User Developer Story in Dark-mode

Comment: It's not at all clear to me where the issue is. Are you talking about the light-colored "Facebook" banner/masthead, and how that doesn't blend well with a dark-themed background?

Comment: Yes, I meant that BG color

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, looks like we missed this one when converting to dark mode. I've got a pull request to make sure these colors are getting translated correctly. Probably won't get merged and deployed until next week.

Pay no mind to the downvotes. This is a real bug that was worth filing. Thanks!