# Comment formatting help isn't dark enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode

I just noticed something wrong with Stack Overflow dark mode feature as screen-shot below.

[image]

I am wondering if I there is an official way to "open issue" regarding the problem. So other people could vote if they experience the same and developer can prioritize fixes based on public opinion.

Comment: you report it here..

Comment: Reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/397021#397021), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/396329#396329), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/396028#396028). [Marked as "status-completed", though](https://cln.sh/dndGOH)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed earlier this week.

Light mode version:

[image]

Dark mode version:

[image]

Thanks for the report!