# Dark mode not working in the Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-declined, developer-story, design

I'm using the most recent version of the platform using Chrome on my Android device.

As you can see from my preferences (click on images for full size)

[image: Dark mode preferred]

I'm particularly interested in using the Dark mode version. Yet, when clicking in the "Developer Story" tab this is what I get

[image: Developer Story not dark]

Know that in Meta and other communities the Dark mode isn't available but I feel this page would be meant to be dark too.

Comment: [_“There are some outstanding issues, particularly related to the Developer Story page, which is difficult to fix without breaking a lot of things.”_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4642212), [_“Developer Story page is suddenly ignoring selected theme”_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396881/4642212) and [5 other entries about the developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/4642212). This is a known issue.

Comment: This will not be implemented because dev story is being removed in a few months. Announcement banners will be added soon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for mentioning this!

Dev Story is one of the outstanding parts of the Dark Mode project that we haven't wrapped up. We'd wanted to get Dev Story available in Dark Mode but it required a ton more work than we had time for so it's going to be light mode only for the time being.

I don't know when we'll be able to get back to this but I will try to update the answer here when we roll it out.