# The tabs on the moderation tools page are unreadable

Tags: bug, dark-mode, moderator-tools

The tabs on the [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) page are unreadable. See screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

The background is black with black text.

Comment: This is already known. _“There are a couple of issues we’re already aware of that we’re working on but weren't able to clean up before release: […] Various tabs: There are still some legacy filter tabs on a few pages that we need to convert to newer components”_ from [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4642212).