# Unthemed visit calendar

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know if its intentional or not, but this calendar isn't themed to support dark-mode.

(To see this, click `Visited x days, y consecutive` under [https://stackoverflow.com/users/{userId}/{userName}?tab=profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/%7BuserId%7D/%7BuserName%7D?tab=profile))

[image]

I was wondering can it be dark-themed for dark-mode? It looks totally *out of place* when the whole page is following a *dark* suit.

Comment: Already reported here: [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396281/4642212) and indexed here: [Complete list of reported feature requests and bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/4642212).