# Informational banner for suggested edits ("Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed…") is unreadable in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode

In the dark mode, when you are editing another person's post, you see this informative message. To be honest, it doesn't cause any problems, but I must say that it is not readable enough.

[image: 1]

Comment: Even though I suggest edits frequently, I never actually noticed this. Surprisingly, no one else has seemed to notice this. It's not in [this list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/12984567) of dark mode bugs.

Comment: yes this a bug but who will correct this or change this??

Comment: In many years SO existed no one read this message even when it was not in such hard to read state... So while indeed it is a bug fixing it would be purely for appearance... and really not worth fixing on its own (likely will get fixed with some other styling so). As result not sure how to vote on this - on one hand I think it totally useless, on other hand it is real bug...

Comment: This is just an old post notice style which should be replaced by a newer post notice Stacks component.

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov sir how this bug can be solved ??

Comment: The designers monitor bugs reported on Meta, and they sometimes even fix them. Patience is required, as the design team is small, and even things that *look* simple to fix often require more effort than meets the eye. Just upvote the bug report if you agree this is something that should be fixed.

Comment: @KUMAR if that is critical for you personally just create custom style for browser of your choice... Otherwise as Cody Gray said some dev/designer form the company may notice this post and fix the issues or more likely as user4642212 said it will be fixed when (if) this "old post notice style" would get enough attention to be fixed, or even more likely they redesign the notice altogether in some future version...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov  okay sir , its great if SO  dev/designer will work. but i am not in need for create custom style for browser of your choice.

Comment: This really hasn't been reported before?

Comment: This has been fixed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403239/poor-contrast-on-edit-page-in-dark-mode