# Poor contrast on edit page in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, design, dark-mode

### Edit Notice

When editing a post that will be placed into a queue for review, a notice is shown that has poor text contrast in dark mode. It has a color contrast ratio of 1.42:

[image: A screenshot of a Stack Overflow edit page that has a notice with light gray text on a light yellow background. There is some text related to editing a question that is highlighted by Chrome's element picker. Chrome has a popover showing some details about that text, including one item that says "Contrast: 1.42" and shows a yellow exclamation point to say that this is not accessible.]

The notice element has the classes `s-notice s-notice__warning newuser`. Removing the `newuser` class fixes the color contrast problems and gives a 6.61 color contrast ratio:

[image: enter image description hereA screenshot of a Stack Overflow edit page that has a notice with light gray text on a dark yellow background. There is some text related to editing a question that is highlighted by Chrome's element picker. Chrome has a popover showing some details about that text, including one item that says "Contrast: 6.61" and shows a green checkmark to say that this is accessible.]

---

### Question Hyperlink

The link to the question has poor color contrast with a color contrast ratio of 1.52:

[image: An example hyperlink to a question title that has black text on a dark gray background]

[image: Chrome's popover for that element that describes some properties of the text, including a color contrast ratio of 1.52 with a yellow exclamation point to say that this is not accessible.]

The hyperlink has the class `question-hyperlink`. Removing this class entirely fixes the color contrast and has a color contrast ratio of 5.51:

[image: An example hyperlink to a question title that has bold blue text on a dark gray background]

[image: Chrome's popover for that element that describes some properties of the text, including a color contrast ratio of 5.21 with a green checkmark to say that this is accessible.]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed! Thanks for helping track this down. Classic old vs. new classes. It’ll go live after a merge and build, but might take a second after this American holiday week.