# Non readable alert with dark theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, dark-mode, banner

When using the dark theme and an unsupported browser user-agent, an alert is shown but it's unreadable due to low contrast.

[image: alert screenshot]

The alert reads:

> Sorry, we no longer support your browser
>
> Please upgrade to Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, or Firefox. Learn more about our browser support.

Comment: Seems like a daft question, but have you considered updating to a supported browser? I do wonder if the fact it's displayed as it is because the browser you are using doesn't support the CSS; might be worth letting people know what browser you are using.

Comment: @Larnu Seems like a Catch-22. If you can't read the message you don't know to load up another browser. Devs can easily include adequate legacy browser css for that specific message

Comment: Which is why I asked you what browser you are using @charlietfl . The Devs have no chance of making sure it works in your unsupported browser, when you don't tell them what browser it is.

Comment: What browser were you using when you got this banner?

Comment: How does it look in the unsupported browser when you set it to light mode? If it is readable there and either the banner or the font has the same color then it is probably just an oversight in the design of dark mode that these two things should not be combined, instead of an actually unsupported CSS feature.

Comment: You lot seem to have misunderstood "and an unsupported browser **user-agent**" - you can spoof user agents in any modern and supported browser. [Here's the same popup](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/627955613737025549/861710189882245146/unknown.png) in Firefox 89.0.1 on Linux with the UA spoofed to IE11 on some version of Windoze. This is a design problem, not a browser problem. (Obligatory reminder that user agents don't affect CSS processing)

Comment: Re *"unreadable due to high contrast"*: Don't you mean something else than "high contrast"?

Comment: @Zoe well, I suppose folks prefer to err on the side of caution given that it is a rare sight these days that people actually ask what they say/write (as I am sure you know). Voted to reopen as upon rereading, it does seem like the design problem. That said, I think I recall this being reported before...

Comment: yeah, it seems like we are fixing this color scheme one popup at a time. It seems like "unsupported" has nothing to do with this, other popups reported: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403239/11407695), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403097/11407695), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395954/11407695)

Comment: @OlegValter Interesting metric .... should be stable in  *"6-8 more popups"*?

Comment: @charlietfl heh, I wonder how many are left to go :) Probably 6-8 more...

Comment: As @Zoe commented the problem is on the design side not the browser. The UA is being spoofed by a Firefox extension called [UserAgent-Switcher](https://github.com/ray-lothian/UserAgent-Switcher/).

Answer (score 3):

Good catch! We’ve identified a fix for this that’ll go out with the next build.

To support browsers that don’t allow for CSS variables, we would inline some styles. The text color wasn’t inlined, so it was being impacted by dark mode. Simply inlining the color solved the problem!

Comment: I'm curious as to why it's marked "status-completed" before the next build had been released.

Comment: Bad answer: Because I told him to :P. Better answer: It's because we merged the PR into the main branch and I _know_ I'm going to forget to update this post when it actually goes live. I'll hit up one of our community managers internally to see how they generally do this.