# Developer story section textbox is not readable in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, developer-story, dark-mode

In the [Edit profile and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) page, in the "Developer Story preferences" menu, the text inside the "Your public link" textbox is not readable in the dark mode.

**When Dark mode is enabled:**

> [image: Dark mode]

**When Dark mode is not enabled:**

> [image: Normal mode]

Comment: Already reported here: [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396656/4642212).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the *locked post* that tells you that, after 17 June 2020, bugs should be posted as new bug reports.

Comment: @CodyGray But the bug is _already_ reported there. This is not a new bug report. How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: A ton of bugs were reported there, but since that's been closed as a bug-tracking mechanism, observed bugs need to be posted as new questions. The developer isn't following that closed, locked, obsolete Q&A.