# Equations in dark mode are black, making them unreadable

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images, dark-mode, mathjax

Equations in dark mode are unreadable because the text is black, and the grey on the edges probably makes it worse. Ideally the text would be changed to a light colour matching the font when in dark mode, but a quick and dirty fix would be to just change the background behind the equations to light, which would make them readable, albeit not too friendly on the eyes.

This screenshot is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/127856/2959891
[image: Screen shot of an equation in dark mode]

Comment: That's an image there, not mathjax. Stack Overflow doesn't support mathjax (as of now).

Comment: You're right, I misread the label of the image as maths markup.

Comment: This has already been reported a few times. See [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396105/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bhargav Rao already said in a comment, Stack Overflow doesn't support MathJax, so any time you see an equation like that in a post, it's just going to be an image.

And that image is almost certainly going to be black-on-white, with no way of dynamically changing the color scheme. So, unfortunately, this is not a bug that can be resolved.

Dark mode is never going to work all that well with inline images in posts. The same issue was noted early on by multiple users when dark mode was first previewed; see, for example, posts by [Alex Telon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396071), [Rahul Wadhwani](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396105), [Niyas Nazar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396192), and [gman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396805).

Comment: I realise now that that is the case. However, perhaps putting a white background behind images with transparency while in dark mode would be a good idea.