# Review tools tab names disappear in dark mode

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, dark-mode

I'm not sure how long this has been the case as I haven't been on the Review tools page for a little while, but I noticed yesterday that the selected tab name is essentially invisible due to having an almost identical colour to the background: `#242729` vs `#2D2D2D`.

[image]

The active "days" selector also has the same problem although it's a bit more readable with a colour of `#3C4146`.

I'm using Firefox 85.0 on Windows 10

Comment: Tabs are a known problem in dark mode. See [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4642212): it’s mentioned in the announcement itself and in various answers.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks, I hadn't seen that post. Considering it was reported on March 30 last year, it's a bit disappointing it hasn't been resolved yet - it does seem it should only be a change in a constant...

Comment: yes, noticed in Top users page too - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers