# Favicon / site icon here on MSO is invisible when OS is in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, favicon

My OS is in dark mode and I discovered today that the site icon here is invisible in many places. I use Edge and actually thought at first that the icon was missing. Here is how it looks in (from top to bottom) Edge, Chrome, and Safari:

> [image: Edge, Chrome, and Safari in dark mode]

Safari seems to detect this lack of contrast and has the sense to throw a light background behind it, but can we fix it so the icon is always visible in every browser? We shouldn't rely on transparency here. The problem is that when people use vertical tabs and collapse the sidebar, they can't see the icon *or* the text, which kind of defeats the purpose of having the icon in the first place.

If you zoom in close enough, you can kind of see it:

> [image]

(I didn't see this site reported specifically in [this old request for feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/61305) and wasn't sure if a new question was the way to go here.)

Comment: With Firefox set to dark mode, you can see the icon, but it does have a low contrast (though not as low as Chrome or Edge). However, with certain themes, invisibility is a problem when the SO Meta tab is selected.