# Missing orange logo with dark theme

Tags: feature-request, design, dark-mode, logo

Now that the dark theme is under reconstruction, could we please have the orange logo back? The white logo is dull.

The orange logo *is* displayed perfectly on the tab of Edge, so why not where it really matters?

[image]

Comment: Also a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423111/6083675).

Comment: @Laurel: No, that 2½ year old pre-new-dark-theme does not answer my question.