# Why can't I set up dark mode on my meta account?

Tags: support, dark-mode

I was hoping to find darkmode also available in the "meta" secction, but this function seems to be disabled. I want to know if is possible to allow the beta darkmode option in "meta".

Comment: Dark mode is not currently supported on Meta. The only site it works on is Stack Overflow, not including Jobs and Meta. From [the announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits): *"At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO [Meta Stack Overflow]."*

Comment: Thanks Cody, didn't found the proper answer on the "related" section.

Comment: Yeah, it's hidden at the bottom of the post, and that's really more of a bug solicitation than an announcement. (Although, being programmers, perhaps "bug solicitation" is how we *define* "announcement". :-p) Do note that there are some userscripts to turn on a dark mode that will work on Meta, like [this one by Sam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386152), if you really want it.