# Dark mode doesn't work in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, dark-mode

It's time to realize again that chat is a thing that exists. Stack Overflow has gotten a dark mode, yet it doesn't work in chat. Given chat is part of Stack Overflow, it should also have a dark mode.

Edit:

There was another question, that we agreed was focused on the main site:
[Should Stack Overflow revisit the dark mode question in light of new situations in 2019 vs 2013 when it was first asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386150/should-stack-overflow-revisit-the-dark-mode-question-in-light-of-new-situations)

Then after dark mode was implemented, there was another (now locked) question to gather things not yet converted to dark mode, where chat was mentioned and then completely ignored in the comments:
[Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits)

Comment: https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/se-chat-dark-theme-plus is golden. Please integrate it into the chat fully (so no stylish/firefox add-on needed).

Comment: I have a userscript for that: [Stack Exchange Dark Mode](https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-exchange-dark-mode)

Comment: @SamuelLiew Finally my eyes are not being burnt alive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386150

Comment: @SamuelLiew I'd say the linked issue is a feature request implemented by now, while this one is a bug report to fix the half-assed feature (or like, 90%-assed to be fair).

Comment: Q&A and chat are two separate systems, there is no bug since dark mode wasn't implemented in chat, so I converted this into a feature request.

Comment: Made a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/8927/dark-mode-4-chats) for this.