# reCAPTCHA widget does not use the dark theme in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, user-experience, dark-mode, captcha

I usually don't come across a lot of forms on Stack Overflow. But today, when I clicked on the [**Contact Us** section in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), I came across this form:

[image: Contact Us form in dark mode]

Something looked off, I saw that big fat reCAPTCHA widget stand out as it still used the light theme.

##### From the reCAPTCHA [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-customize-the-recaptcha-widget-or-badge):

[image: reCAPTCHA Theme Variants]

I'm not quite sure where else Stack Overflow uses reCAPTCHA, but was almost sure that I would find one on the [Sign Up](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2Fusers%2Fstory%2Fcurrent) page (sign out or use Incognito mode on Chrome to view the page).
I think Stack Overflow is still working on the dark version of the landing and sign-up page for anonymous users as I would argue that the default theme must be **System Setting** instead of **Light** for a seamless experience to new users.

Comment: Here is a route you can always use for testing: https://stackoverflow.com/captcha

Comment: Dark Mode is still in beta for Stack Overflow Q&A, is it not? The Contact Us page is not part of Q&A, so I don't see how this could be a [bug]. A [feature-request] perhaps.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Two points: 1) Who said that Dark Mode is just for Q&A? AFAICT, it's for Stack Overflow as a whole; otherwise, why is the Contact Us page using Dark Mode, to begin with? Also, in the announcement post, there are many reported (and some fixed) bugs in pages that aren't Q&A. 2) According to the [the announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/8967612), Dark Mode is already out of beta.

Comment: @41686d6564 Thanks for the pointer to the fact that it's no longer in beta. I missed that. I was reading a post about a dark mode issue that wasn't on Q&A and saw a diamond person say it was only for Q&A and had changed the post from a [bug] to a [feature-request]. Of course, now I can't find the post, so I look like an idiot, but I'm used to that... I sit corrected.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No worries :) I think you're referring to this post: [Dark mode doesn't work in chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402990/8967612). Chat is different though as it's a separate sub-domain with a separate design; It's similar to the fact that Meta.SO still doesn't have Dark Mode.