# How can I change the code snippet CodeMirror theme?

Tags: support

The JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) uses the popular library CodeMirror that has support for [amazing themes](https://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html#ambiance).

How can we change this in Stack Overflow?

I'm struggling with extensions to make this coding website use a dark theme. This should be a default option, but it seems like Stack Overflow is averse to dark themes.

Comment: Is this a feature request _or_ a request for support? Those two are generally mutually exclusive.

Comment: I removed the `feature-request`tag since there's no need to request such an obvious theme requirement for a coding website, am I right?.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd classify it as an obvious requirement.

Comment: Well, at least more than 500 ppl agree with me https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274388/why-is-there-no-dark-theme-on-so

Comment: ... except that question is suggesting a dark theme for the SITE, not just the code snippet editor. Two different things.

Comment: They disagree that a user wants a dark theme? Why? I'm not asking to delete the white theme. This will NOT affect who don't want a dark theme so tell me: why would you disagree with it?

Comment: Maybe they think it's not necessary. Maybe they think it's not worth the developer's time / effort. Maybe they don't like dark themes. Who are we to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's still no option to change the snippet theme, but the Stylus theme on this link https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark does change the snippet to a dark theme.

Despite Stylus providing several dark themes for Stack Overflow, this was the only one to properly change the snippet editor colors. Still it would be awesome to be able to change the code highlight colors with those CodeMirror themes.

Anybody who spends much time in front of a computer knows that little things, like ergonomics, or responsiveness, or design, can really affect the quality of your digital experience.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

There is no way to change what theme is used, other than overriding the whole CSS file, client-side (userscript / userstyle).