# Can site options be changed to allow a customized palette?

Tags: support

I use Firefox and prefer to have a customized palette (dark background, yellow letters). When I use this palette on this site I can not enter and see text, I think because this site forces a dark color for text input and this is 'unseeable' in my palette. In order to enter text I need to specify (in Firefox->Options->General->Colors) "use System Colors" which provides a light background and dark text.

There are other sites in which I can interface. Is there any setting that will allow my dark background to be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no dark theme on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274388/why-is-there-no-dark-theme-on-so)