# Can SO be changed to allow a dark browser theme?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

When I use my 'dark' browser theme input characters can not be seen on SO. This is because the input areas are 'dark' and display black characters. In my case, the appearance of input areas is dark blue  (my theme) and the input characters are black. Blank and blue don't provide a viewable I/F.

My question is can the input areas be changed so that the input is viewable.

For example, Fidelity.com has Username/Password fields given as text areas with a white background. Other sites do it differently. I think that the issue is that SO pages insist on using the browser color scheme and default to black characters.

But, in this case, I see what I am typing by looked at the SO output of my text (below the input text area), an in this window the characters are yellow.

Comment: CSS tweaks are probably bound by what is needed on other sites in the network as well. let me link to the MSE post on this topic https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/having-a-dark-theme-for-stack-exchange-sites/336626#336626

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274390/578411