# Why was dark mode such a challenge to implement?

Tags: discussion, dark-mode

I'm specifically not trying to be an armchair critic - I ask this out of pure naivety, without knowing about the complexities of web design. What are the main challenges involved in implementing dark mode?

Comment: Yes, it's not just changing the background and text color. It's changing every color defined on the site, including those used in third-party scripts (which often assume a white background). The nice box-shadow you see under the header? that probably needs to be reversed. The glow around focused input fields? Looks a little spooky against a dark background, etc., etc., ad nauseum.

Comment: [*"Tomorrow, we will publish a blog post from Aaron Shekey, our design systems lead, detailing the process behind the creation of this new feature."*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/)

Comment: Dark mode is about changing the stylesheet rules for the website. For a company with tens of millions of dollars of revenue, there is no good explanation for why changing the stylesheet rules took so many years.

Comment: @Vlaz - As I said in the OP, I know literally nothing about web design. The question is an honest one because I'm interested in the complexities that go behind web design which I am not aware of.

Comment: @Lou it's a little bit insulting to suggest it's super easy when you've not in fact even tried it. Changing the background and text colour is *trivial* - it's just setting the `background-color` and `color` CSS properties. Had you tried it, it should have been plain to see there is more work needed. The constant bug reports that keep coming in about stuff that doesn't look right is also indicative of this not being a simple process.

Comment: @VLAZ - It's a little bit insulting to assume bad faith when I've clarified twice that my question comes from naivety and ignorance about the complexities involved, as a result of not being a web designer, and specifically not because I'm assuming it's easy. In much the same way that someone with no experience of baking might earnestly be interested to know what challenges arise when making a cake, without disrespecting bakers or their skills. I'm the non-baker here.

Comment: I'd suggest not asking bakers "Why did it take you so long to make a cake, isn't just it just mixing flour and eggs? " if you're interested in the process, then. Because otherwise your clarifications come across as "I'm not racist, *but*..."  type statements.

Comment: @VLAZ - Fair enough point, I've edited the question to better reflect the tone I was going for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## If *only* it were that simple.

<sup>(Yes, that's intentionally larger than normal because MY GOD do you know how many web devs would jump for joy if just one or two tweaks to get "dark mode" was all it took)</sup>

One of the big things going against a simple dark mode was that [it would've meant supporting two style templates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274390/1079354), which would mean double the overhead for an already shoestring development effort, and would definitely not be palatable or sustainable long term.

To change this, [Stack Overflow Design](https://stackoverflow.design) was brought up as a way to standardize the design elements of Stack Overflow, including - you guessed it - provide a more templateable and maintainable CSS framework with reusable components.  I believe that this was more borne out of the pain of having to do custom styles for every site on the network, and that started to show the same hallmarks of maintainability as having multiple dark modes for a given site.

So, in that vein, Stacks had matured enough back in December? January? for it to be used as a part of the new [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog), which also came with its own automatic Dark Mode.  From there, it was just a matter of time before those Stacks improvements could make their way to Stack Overflow proper, and (potentially, eventually) the rest of the network.